# Typescript: ReturnType of overloaded function

Tags: typescript

The type given by `ReturnType` seems to depend on the order the overload signatures are written

```
function applyChanges1(input: string): number
function applyChanges1(input: number): string
function applyChanges1(input: number | string): number | string {
  return typeof input === "number" ? input.toString() : input.length
}

function applyChanges2(input: number): string
function applyChanges2(input: string): number
function applyChanges2(input: number | string): number | string {
  return typeof input === "number" ? input.toString() : input.length
}

type Ret1 = ReturnType<typeof applyChanges1> // string
type Ret2 = ReturnType<typeof applyChanges2> // number
```

It seems to take the return type of the last overload signature which seems quite arbitrary. I was expecting both `Ret1` and `Ret2` to be `string | number`. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Matt McCutchen points this is a limitation of `ReturnType` and in general conditional types and multiple overload signatures.

We can however construct a type that will return all overloaded return types for up to an arbitrary number of overloads:

```
function applyChanges1(input: string): number
function applyChanges1(input: number): string
function applyChanges1(input: number | string): number | string {
  return typeof input === "number" ? input.toString() : input.length
}

function applyChanges2(input: number): string
function applyChanges2(input: string): number
function applyChanges2(input: number | string): number | string {
  return typeof input === "number" ? input.toString() : input.length
}


type OverloadedReturnType<T> = 
    T extends { (...args: any[]) : infer R; (...args: any[]) : infer R; (...args: any[]) : infer R ; (...args: any[]) : infer R } ? R  :
    T extends { (...args: any[]) : infer R; (...args: any[]) : infer R; (...args: any[]) : infer R } ? R  :
    T extends { (...args: any[]) : infer R; (...args: any[]) : infer R } ? R  :
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any


type RetO1 = OverloadedReturnType<typeof applyChanges1> // string | number 
type RetO2 = OverloadedReturnType<typeof applyChanges2> // number | string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwA6oDYE8DCALZMAcwFMBnARgAoYxUQoAuRMqAJ1qIEpmwQBbAEYk2AWABQoSLAQp02fIVKUadBrwHC2PFu04Sp0eEjSZcBYuWq16TRHyEjEAH10diOh1pdvOiAN4SiIhsJFAgbEhQWKgkcMCINgyIALxpiABEXiIZiAD8iWpQAHRQcADKesRUXIjMSSUYJMRQeBIAvhIG4EaypgoWygBMqrYajtrMrO5E3dLGcmaKlmQjDVNV3ONac70m8uZK5GtF206u05yemue+xAFBIWERUTFxCQ2p6Vk3bLkFDVKFU2NTqhVsxSaLTa4k64i64misUQAHkAG4iDBwZAAExIOIASs9IgAVN4AHhJAD5UohHsESYgSAAPKDNHFkAKIKjFXnINhEMjMQhYADaAF1avUwMAnASANzc3nFfmC4VgMWSsG0WVsRAKpV8gVClAaiVSwq6-WIRU8o1q02ai06uWIdr5a11emIRkstlgDlcu0q43qp3amVy23K1UmkXmiNWg3B2NhhPSpNuj0E4KMb2+1nszn+Q0hh3xrUZqOl1OO9OW13ugo5r3iYIMpmFgOclOhutalI0l16nPNsEihESJEkfVhFEUWnozHYvGE4lgMmxcnT+KLAZHSg0gD0R7uRB82T1U7es6gKKGi4xbCxuPxRPCpIpO4S-UOKyGx6npePiXMQQA)

The version above will work for up to 4 overload signatures (whatever they may be) but can easily (if not prettily) be extended to more.

We can even get a union of possible argument types in the same way:

```
type OverloadedParameters<T> = 
    T extends { (...args: infer A1) : any; (...args: infer A2) : any; (...args: infer A3) : any ; (...args: infer A4) : any } ? A1|A2|A3|A4  :
    T extends { (...args: infer A1) : any; (...args: infer A2) : any; (...args: infer A3) : any } ? A1|A2|A3 :
    T extends { (...args: infer A1) : any; (...args: infer A2) : any } ? A1|A2  :
    T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : any


type Params01 = OverloadedParameters<typeof applyChanges1> // [string] | [number]
type Params02 = OverloadedParameters<typeof applyChanges2>  // [number] | [string]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwA6oDYE8DCALZMAcwFMBnARgAoYxUQoAuRMqAJ1qIEpmwQBbAEYk2AWABQoSLAQp02fIVKUadBrwHC2PFu04Sp0eEjSZcBYuWq16TRHyEjEAH10diOh1pdvOiAN4SiIhsJFAgbEhQWKgkcMCINgyIALxpiABEXiIZiAD8iWpQAHRQcADKesRUXIjMSSUYJMRQeBIAvhIG4EaypgoWygBMqrYajtrMrO5E3dLGcmaKlmQjDVNV3ONac70m8uZK5GtF206u05yemue+xAFBIWERUTFxCQ2p6Vk3bLkFDVKFU2NTqhVsxSaLTa4k64i64misUQAHkAG4iDBwZAAExIOIASs9IgAVN4AHhJAD5UohHsESYgSAAPKDNHFkAKIKjFXnINhEMjMQhYADaAF1avUwMAnASANzc3nFfmC4VgMWSsG0WVsRAKpV8gVClAaiVSwq6-WIRU8o1q02ai06uWIdr5a11emIRkstlgDlcu0q43qp3amVy23K1UmkXmiNWg3B2NhhPSpNuj0E4KMb2+1nszn+Q0hh3xrUZqOl1OO9OW13ugo5r3iYIMpmFgOclOhutalI0l16nPNsEihESJEkfVhFEUWnozHYvGE4lgMmxcnT+KLAZHSg0gD0R7uRB82T1U7es6gKKGi4xbCxuPxRPCpIpO4S-UOKyGx6npePiXMQk7whB06ok+L6rgACvyyD8GEIhkJSNIpHSbbtgW-qBiWvYOsOiAAIIUBaIrRvaJrESRQwURqVFljRkZ6iRADMDFYDaNZ9rRAAsXFZgUZHOHRYnsWJ-G5vmnZ4cWvFEaxpHkeOjGKSxVp0VxTG1rRnFqdxTYqWJQwSa27Y+nJRZBjGfHKWROkaVWbH0YZwkmXRMnYR2fo2YRmlOCRtSDo6HokYZ4FQQhbBIWQAAMC6YUuz4rviMVIShbBod+e5-soFCAYgoqgUQ4o+KKl7iteyIZfwCUPslMFpTidVZTlby7r+yzDDSiAnsVVUVaV1UQUAA)

Comment: Extremely interesting. I've seen a lot of your responses to other typescript questions around which are consistently enlightening. I am curious as to how you acquired all this knowledge haha.

Comment: @LionelTay Not sure .. happened in time. I used to tinker with the compiler a while back and that helped, I also read the PR as each realese comes out, they are very enlightening. Also answering question hears helps me acumulate  knowledge :)

Comment: Hmm, so I think that `OverloadedRetrunType<F>` always passes the first "four overload" test if `F` is a function type, even if it has fewer than four overload signatures.  It's almost a coincidence that the inferred type of `R` is the right value (it becomes a union of the successfully inferred types).  If you tried to break it into separate return types `infer R ... infer S ... `, you'd get a lot of `{}` returns.  This is frustrating...

Comment: @jcalz I'm seeing the same thing. If you do something like `T extends {
        (...args: any[]): infer R1;
        (...args: any[]): infer R2;
        (...args: any[]): infer R3;
        (...args: any[]): infer R4;
    } ? R1 | R2 | R3 | R4 ...rest of code` instead, you can clearly see it occur in the union. Say you had 3 overloads then you would get `InferedType1 | InferedType2 | InferedTyp3 | {}`.

Comment: @MarthinusEngelbrecht The behavior around multiple overloads and conditional types is a bit wierd and there are sub bugs in there. Me and jcalz stumbled on different behaviors depending on the actual overloads, and jcalz reported a bug on it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28867

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir cool, thanks for the info. Will keep my eye on it. At least I know now that it's not just me doing something wrong.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir there's a question I might close as a duplicate of this one, but fyi [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218) has a modified version of the overload inference from this answer and maybe you want to incorporate part of it here?

Comment: This helped me extract a funky method parameter type that wasn't itself exported, so I could stinkin' strongly type my class without duplicating the source `.d.ts` file. Amazing!

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem -- I needed to pick the `ReturnType` of the **exact** overload, based on the **arguments** I have.

e.g.:

```
function applyChanges1(input: string): number
function applyChanges1(input: number): string
function applyChanges1(input: boolean): object
function applyChanges1(input: number | string | boolean): number | string | object {
    return typeof input === "number" ? input.toString()
         : typeof input === "boolean" ? { input }
         : input.length;
}


// Needed:

type Ret11 = ReturnTypeWithArgs<typeof applyChanges1, [string]> // number
type Ret12 = ReturnTypeWithArgs<typeof applyChanges1, [number]> // string
type Ret13 = ReturnTypeWithArgs<typeof applyChanges1, [boolean]> // object
type Ret14 = ReturnTypeWithArgs<typeof applyChanges1, [number | string]> // number | string
type Ret15 = ReturnTypeWithArgs<typeof applyChanges1, [number | boolean]> // string | object
type Ret16 = ReturnTypeWithArgs<typeof applyChanges1, [number | string | boolean]> // number | string | object
```

So I created the following `ReturnTypeWithArgs` utility based on the beautiful answer of [@Titian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) above and using `Extract`.

```
type ReturnTypeWithArgs<T extends (...args: any[]) => any, ARGS_T> =
    Extract<
        T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; (...args: infer A3): infer R3; (...args: infer A4): infer R4; } ? [A1, R1] | [A2, R2] | [A3, R3] | [A4, R4] :
        T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; (...args: infer A3): infer R3; } ? [A1, R1] | [A2, R2] | [A3, R3] :
        T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; } ? [A1, R1] | [A2, R2] :
        T extends { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; } ? [A1, R1] :
        never,
        [ARGS_T, any]
    >[1]
```

It works like a charm!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-IFiCFsPhSIK6sl2o9+oVOsdqqLlpLSv1RorppdxfddbtPrSTv9A2TwdeFCTEajg8B8deifmWYFuZFBfFrqtbflHf7zZrrZN9ZXLzNxx7QYoIYH4cNw8n2cFULzosLFrdjbL26rAd7h-7GanJTAJAAbiIKZ+xRBnSjKfFSOL4lmxK4gODxPK85QUBQbQIRUVTfHU-xApiYJPMsxhyGYihvriGScPipIAPSUaE6giI8PyoRQBooW8aFfD8WF4MCoK4T8+GyKYCgWFSuI9CIFGINRMS6PBbEULarHvOhnEAtxOF4Y0BFCYEJGbEkYCSdJOSeFADF1ExnpKexGF-GpPHgppfiEcJlCieJaTRGRxBGTRHnpNMRDmc88kAKzWR8tlcQ5fFLFpgkBMR7l0Z5CRbIQvkyXE0QmV4cmIQAbBFKmYfZGn8fF-hESJyb+V5gXxPp2yZXVWVZDl7imUAA)

---

PS. In my real case I have 7 overloads, so wish me luck! ;D

Answer (score 8):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24275#issuecomment-390701982).  The TypeScript team's recommendation is to include a "most general" overload signature as your last overload signature, e.g.:

```
function applyChanges1(input: string): number
function applyChanges1(input: number): string
function applyChanges1(input: number | string): number | string
function applyChanges1(input: number | string): number | string {
  return typeof input === "number" ? input.toString() : input.length
}
```

Titian Cernicova-Dragomir has a nicer alternate solution in his answer.

Comment: Yes, but it can be done without the extra overload,  I suggested a way that got picked up in one of the GitHub tickes you commented on: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26048. Is there a reason this is not recommended that you know of ? Except the ugliness :)

Comment: I guess I was just answering the question about `ReturnType` and not thinking about alternative solutions, and I had forgotten about your solution anyway.  Thanks for posting it.