# Extract call signature from a type

Tags: typescript

Given a type containing both a call signature and additional properties such as:

```js
export interface Foo<T> {
    (arg: T): T;
    doFoo(): void;
}
```

How can we type a function which implements the call signature of this type?

```js
// Property 'doFoo' is missing in type '(arg: string) => string'
// but required in type 'Foo<string>'.
const foo: Foo<string> = (arg: string) => arg;
```

One way to exclude the call signature is to use a mapped type since the call signature will not be in `keyof Foo<T>`:

```js
type FooProperties<T> = { [K in keyof Foo<T>]: Foo<T>[K] };

const foo: FooProperties<string> = {
    doFoo() {}
};
```

But how can we get the opposite, that is *only* the call signature so we can write the following?

```js
type FooSignature<T> = /* …? */

const foo: FooSignature<string> = (arg: string) => arg;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ReturnType` and `Parameters` built-in types to extract the parameters and return type and rebuild the signature:

```
export interface Foo<T> {
    (arg: T): T;
    doFoo(): void;
}

type JustSignature<T extends (...a: any[]) => unknown> = (...a: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>

type FooSignature<T> = JustSignature<Foo<T>>

const foo: FooSignature<string> = (arg: string) => arg;
```

Note: For a solution that works for multiple overloads see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968958/typescript-extract-multiple-call-signatures-from-interface/59969114#59969114)

Comment: Thanks Titian! Didn't occur to me at all, I kept thinking about mapped types. Appreciate all your work on Typescript on SO.

Comment: @IngoBürk thanks, keep the question coming :) It's been a slow couple of weeks on SO for TS, at least insofar as language questions are concerned :)

Comment: Looks like it does not work when there are more than one call signature (function overloading). `JustSignature` picks the latest call signature in the overload list.

Comment: @htulipe that is true extracting multiple signatures is possible but messy (something like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function), and this will not work for generics either. It is a limited solution for the problem posed in the original question.

Comment: Ok I just posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968958/typescript-extract-multiple-call-signatures-from-interface

Comment: @htulipe just posted an answer 

Comment: Need some real time notifications on SO 