# how to pass interface types through a intermediate function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type the following function so that the types of the function itself (`useDeviceSettings`) match the types of `useSettings`:

```js
export const useDeviceSettings = (...args) => {
  const useSettings = getStoreHook() // this return type is `UseStore`, described below.

  return useSettings(...args)
}


const isSyncOn = useDeviceSettings((state) => state.isSyncOn)
```

the types of `useSettings` come from [Zustand](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand) and are as follows:

```js
export interface UseStore<T extends State> {
    (): T;
    <U>(selector: StateSelector<T, U>, equalityFn?: EqualityChecker<U>): U;
    setState: SetState<T>;
    getState: GetState<T>;
    subscribe: Subscribe<T>;
    destroy: Destroy;
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that in the above I get:

```
Rest parameter 'args' implicitly has an 'any[]' type. ts(7019)
```

I've also tried the following:

```js
export const useDeviceSettings = (…args: Parameters<DeviceSettingsStore>) => {
  const useSettings = getStoreHook()

  return useSettings(...args)
}
```

but I think this messes with the generics because while `U` should be typed when using the 2nd function in the interface it no longer is in this case.

```
Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. ts(2488)
```

So far the only way I can get this to work is the following:

```js
export const useDeviceSettings = () => {
  const useDS = getStoreHook()

  return useDS
}
```

but this means in use I need to do the following:

```js
const isSyncOn = useDeviceSettings()((state) => state.isSyncOn)
```

which feels wrong/unnecessary.

Comment: can you just do `const useDeviceSettings: typeof useSettings = ...` or does useSettings have other properties like `subscribe` (I'm not totally clear how the `UseStore` interface is related)

Comment: As a side note, why are you using a useCallback? I can't see any valid reason to use it here. Note that abusing useCallback and useMemo can negatively impact performance.

Comment: It seems that Parameters<DeviceSettingsStore> is unknown for some reason. Could we see what the DeviceSettingsStore type looks like, please?

Comment: "which feels wrong in unnecessary". Well, with a bit of umformulieren:

`const useDeviceSettingsSelector = useStore((store) => store.useDeviceSettings)

const isSyncOn = useDeviceSettingsSelector((state) => state.isSyncOn)
`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen maybe I shouldn't have keep the `useStore` bit in the example. the type returned by that is the `UseStore` interface that I describe, so that whole line is not really relevant.

Comment: @jperl just following the example here: https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/recipes#memoizing-selectors

`DeviceSettingsStore` is of type `UseStore` above, but with `T` filled out.

Comment: Oh my, that's what you meant by Zustand. Thought for a second you were german (which you might be :)) As for memoizing selectors, that's new to me... But then again, it depends how useStore is actually implemented.

Comment: Maybe you would like to edit your post with your comment above (about DeviceSettingsStore) which is crucial piece of information.

Comment: @jperl yep, I updated the above to simplify things!

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of issues that compound to make this not quite possible, The first is you want to [extract the call signature from `UseStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376089/extract-call-signature-from-a-type) but preserving its generic which is not possible with TS 4.5 as far as I am aware.

```
interface ExampleCallable{
  a: string,
  <U>(a:U): U
}
// this doesn't have a generic, just unknown :(
type extractedSignature = ExampleCallable extends ((...args:infer A)=>infer R) ? ((...args:A)=>R) : never
```

the second thing is that `UseStore` has 2 overloads, so even extracting the call signatures would not let you just use it to infer the arguments since typescript is not happy with that:

```
interface ExampleFunc {
  (): string;
  (a:string, b?:number): string;
}
// say we had a function of this signature and we just want a wrapper for it
declare const baseFunc: ExampleFunc
// TS is not happy about this as long as there is 2 or more overloads
const f: ExampleFunc = (...args)=>{
  console.log("DEBUGGING FOR EXAMPLE!")
  return baseFunc(...args); 
}
```

So even if you could extract the call signature it wouldn't help automate the desirable behaviour.  My recommendation would be to just say you have the same call signature and just bypass the types inside the functions:

```
// if the library function also has complicated generics you can write this actual function so the generics get resolved in here
// and you can use `typeof getStoreHook` to get the actual value you are interested in
function getStoreHook(){
  return useStore(...);
}
type MatchedSig = ReturnType<typeof getStoreHook>;
// we use `& Record<keyof MatchedSig, unknown>` to ensure that if someone tries 
// to use the fields defined in the original UseStore it will not think they are valid properties
export const useDeviceSettings:MatchedSig & Record<keyof MatchedSig, unknown> = ((...args: any[])=>{
  const useSettings = getStoreHook();
  return (useSettings as any)(...args)
}) as any;

// useDeviceSettings.setState should be unknown, I wasn't able to test properly
```