# Parameters generic of overloaded function doesn't contain all options

Tags: typescript, generics, parameters

Given an overloaded function `example`.

```
function example(a: string): number
function example(a: string, b?: string): number { 
  return 1
}

type Result = Parameters<typeof example>
```

I'd expect Result to contain ALL options for arguments of `example`, not just the first / top-most argument set. How can I get the parameters?

Comment: The last one doesn't actually count, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads; the type of example is *only* the one overload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: ReturnType of overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function)

Answer (score 10):

In the answers to [the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function) the limitation mentioned in [@ford04's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59536085/2887218), that `infer` only looks at the last overloaded signature, is acknowledged.  This is a missing feature or design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732) for a relevant feature request.

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52761156/2887218) shows it's not *completely* impossible; you can tease out some information about overloads, at least for functions with up to some arbitrary fixed number of them (this is still true as of TypeScript 4.8; recursive conditional types don't help).  But it's hairy and ugly and [there might be bugs in it, see microsoft/TypeScript#28867](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28867).  Here's one way of doing it:

```
type Overloads<T> =
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
    (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3;
    (...args: infer A4): infer R4
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1,
    (...args: A2) => R2,
    (...args: A3) => R3,
    (...args: A4) => R4
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
    (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1,
    (...args: A2) => R2,
    (...args: A3) => R3
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
    (...args: infer A2): infer R2
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1,
    (...args: A2) => R2
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1
  ] : any

type OverloadedParameters<T> =
  Overloads<T> extends infer O ?
  { [K in keyof O]: Parameters<Extract<O[K], (...args: any) => any>> } : never

type OverloadedReturnType<T> =
  Overloads<T> extends infer O ?
  { [K in keyof O]: ReturnType<Extract<O[K], (...args: any) => any>> } : never
```

The `Overloads<T>` type alias takes a function type `T` and returns a tuple of its call signatures (for up to four overloads).  And `OverloadedParameters<T>` and `OverloadedReturnType<T>` map `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` over that tuple, respectively.

Let's see it in action (after correcting your example so that it actually has multiple overloads, as done in the other answer):

```
function example(a: string): number
function example(a: string, b: string): number
function example(a: string, b?: string): number {
  return 1
}

type ExampleOverloads = Overloads<typeof example>
// type ExampleOverloads = [(a: string) => number, (a: string, b: string) => number]

type ExampleParameters = OverloadedParameters<typeof example>
// type ExampleParameters = [[string], [string, string]]
```

Looks reasonable to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgGwPYEMAmBnAPAFQD4oBeAKCinyggA9gIA7HKAbwsqgAoA6P9RAHNsALigBLRgDMkUAIIBGAJRjJMxFABKCgNzc+PAcNXTZcgEwqJpjZvM6OlXvyGjr6+QGYra2Zs96zoauJh5yACw+NlrhHAC+UAD8UADajvouxvLKpMTaADQZwVkWSrla5vnpQUZuct7l-oU1IfKRjbGUALpQYtR0DMzYbNUGtaFmyhO2ukXj7maW0xUOnHOtvhr1UR7+8Umpo5l1OSR5Cs1jraWNlUfFdQ1nWp4cPX009Ews7GstWZtsjs-LN-m5AaVlnZ9sk0n8riVTudLscxDdntDur0qJ9Bj97vMIVMFjMYYd4aigY0FG9sehGCAyGRQJBYAgUBhMBBMAAFAToAC2EAYiDwRFIHHgSDQWDFxAG32GgJgSQ4rFSAGlrFAANYQECoKSwLpiPmIQXCpB4ACi9HNAGNgLgYCkNV0UQ8xPSQGVnt7CMQEmJGBB2UyWdApRysNzNMKAK6IRj4cAQAjEciUKMynDp3GKkmwVWUdWu7V6g1GmAmrQJpMpyC4W3AB1Ol1uj3zb2+4j+wPYkNhshSeOMR3iVCMT6CsDICBcdBibAtySCKyMeMCgBGSGHo-Hk+nAtn88XUGXiFXhS3S5XjDXwc3O8Qe7HwAnU7oM7nC9vl-v16JH+q7rk+si-FAiB1lONJxOGqZQLa34QNmnLDCQbLSmhuARoaR4noQZAAPREVAEaIbQyGobKpCpL+553mu5QbtuSDNGeF5XlAN4Mf+THPCxz5dPBrJIcec5mhaIroZh0Zcry-JCtJOGpnhX7iRAhEkWRCFiSeklKVatEpCknH3u6qRmYIhRWV0XRAA)

Comment: Thank you for the info and the issue hint (+1). While I probably would not use this in production, this is interesting inference behavior.