# How to get the type of the nth argument of an overloaded method / polymorphic method?

Tags: typescript

I use a library which defines a class like this:

```
// node_modules/@types/ol/control/Zoom.d.ts

export default class Zoom extends Control {

  constructor(opt_options?: Options);

  on(type: 'change', listener: (evt: BaseEvent) => void): EventsKey;
  on(type: 'error', listener: (evt: BaseEvent) => void): EventsKey;
  on(type: 'propertychange', listener: (evt: ObjectEvent) => void): EventsKey;

}
```

Now, I would like to get the type of the first argument of the `on` method.
I expect to get this kind of result:

```
type EventType = "change" | "error" | "propertychange"
```

But sadly, when I try:

```
type EventType = Parameters<InstanceType<typeof zoom>["on"]>[0];
```

The result is like this:

```
type EventType = "propertychange"
```

Only the last declaration seems to be accessible.

Here is a screenshot of VSCode showing this:

[image: VScode screenshot with only propertychange]

On the other hand, typescript still knows the actual type, because VSCode shows me this:

[image]

So there must be a way to get this working.... Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameters generic of overloaded function doesn't contain all options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options)

Answer (score 1):

Overload signatures are not really dealt with programmatically this way; you will generally only see the last (or maybe first?) signature when inferring.  There are ways to tease some info out of the type system, but they're bulky and fragile.

For example: from my answer to [a question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options) , you could define an `Overloads` type function that returns a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of call signatures corresponding to overloads, up to an arbitrary fixed number of overloads.  Here's a way to write it for up to four signatures:

```
type Overloads<T> =
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3; (...args: infer A4): infer R4
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2,
    (...args: A3) => R3, (...args: A4) => R4
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2,
    (...args: A3) => R3
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1
  ] : any
```

Given that, you could write your `EvenType` like this:

```
type EventType = Parameters<Overloads<Zoom['on']>[number]>[0];
// type EventType = "change" | "error" | "propertychange"
```

But I doubt it's worth such a cumbersome type function to do it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgGwPYEMAmBnAPAFQD4oBeAWACgop8oIAPYCAOxygG9LrqAKAOgHpEAc2wAuKAEtmAMyRQAggEYAlBOlzEUAEpKA3FH6CR4qbPkKATGrOadlvV25G+Q0evNaFAZhsb52t4GLm6m-l4ALH6eOhFOAL5QAPxQANpOvAKuJhLKKqTEugA0hlmhudYF9kUZpcbuir5VgSUhOYpRzXFUUAC6UBK0DEys2By1bQ3hiqoedrrBZe3TVtHzDhNLUzE+awHeCclpm-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)