# Specify which overload to read when using Parameters

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the `Parameters` from an overloaded function

```
interface FuncContainer {
    someFunc(name: string, value: number): number;
}
```

Here, I have an interface that has a function `someFunc`.  What I'm really interested in is the type of `value` - this is pretty simple:

```
type Value = Parameters<FuncContainer["someFunc"]>[1]; // Value is type number
```

The problem is when using overloads, the last overload is always used by `Parameters` (via `infer`):

```
interface FuncContainer {
    someFunc(name: string, value: number): number;
    someFunc(name: string): number;
}

type Args = Parameters<FuncContainer["someFunc"]>;    // [str: string]
type Value = Parameters<FuncContainer["someFunc"]>[1]; // undefined
```

I've tried leveraging `extends` with no effect:

```
type Parameter2<F extends (name: string, value: any) => any> = Parameters<F>[1];
type Value = Parameter2<FuncContainer["someFunc"]>; // undefined
```

**Is there any way to specify which overload (by index, by type, whatever) is used when using `Parameters`?**

Comment: As I think the last overload is implementation. That's why it takes the last. Overloads should be ordered from most specific to least specific. From least specific overload (implementation) you can retrieve any parameter type you want.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев The implementation of a function (the lowest) must have the widest type def, and all of the overloads must extend it.  I do not believe that there are any other ordering rules in overloads.  Also: my overloads, here, are just in an interface - there is no implementation.  The idea that it's picking the least specific overload was interesting - I tested it out by flipping the two versions of `someFunc` but it still picked the lower of the two (which made `type Value = ...` equal to `number`.

Comment: The implementation of a function is not part of its call signatures, so @НиколайГольцев's comment doesn't quite apply.   It is true that the ordering of call signatures should be from most specific to least specific, but that's just to help the compiler pick the right one when *calling* it.  But the least specific call signature is not the same as the implementation signature.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107789/how-to-get-the-type-of-the-nth-argument-of-an-overloaded-method-polymorphic-me) but I can't mark it as such because it doesn't have an upvoted answer