# Typescript: Spreading function parameters defined as tuples

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript project where I'm calling `Date` inside of a function. I want to use the same function parameters as the constructor from `Date` which is overloaded:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new(): Date;
    new(value: number | string | Date): Date;
    new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
    // ...
}
```

I would like to use the spread operator in order to pass the parameters to the constructor of `Date`. So my function should hopefully look like that:

```
function myFn(...args: DateComponents): Date {
    return new Date(...args)
}
```

I'm not actually returning a date in my case, but this is just for testing...

The question is now how to define `DateComponents`. I successfully implemented the 3 overloaded signatures of `DateConstructor` separately from each other.

```
// Case A: No argument provided
interface A {
  (): Date;
}
const a: A = function (...args: []): Date {
  return new Date(...args);
}

// Case B: 1 argument provided
interface B {
  (value: number | string | Date): void;
}
const b: B = function (...args: [number | string | Date]): Date {
  return new Date(...args);
}

// Case C: Between 2 and 7 arguments provided
interface C {
  (year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): void;
}
const c: C = function (...args: [number, number, number?, number?, number?, number?, number?]): Date {
  return new Date(...args);
}
```

So far so good, everything works.

- **A:** An empty tuple is used to cover the case where no argument is passed
- **B:** A tuple with one element covers the case where a single number, string or `Date` object is passed
- **C:** A tuple with 2 mandatory and 5 optional number elements covers the cases where 2-7 arguments are passed

If I try to combined these 3 examples into 1, I get this:

```
interface D {
  (): void;
  (value: number | string | Date): void;
  (year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): void;
}
type DateComponents = [] | [number | string | Date] | [number, number, number?, number?, number?, number?, number?];
const d: D = function (...args: DateComponents): Date {
  return new Date(...args); // <-- ERROR: Expected 0-7 arguments, but got 0 or more.
}
```

I get an error saying that Typescript thinks that more than 7 arguments could be passed into the `Date` constructor. I do not understand why because my type `DateComponents` explicitly defines tuples of 0-7 elements.

I could fix this by using some conditions and type assertions, but I'm hoping there is a prettier solution?

[See the code in the Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIBQCUAXMgCJyQDcWAvlggPYgDOYycJ6AvMjAK4gEYYE3wA6CXCgBzZiQDaAXWJkKKbLigQwfKCGQgIAd1WQ8EsVNkFqdLKEixEKAEKYc+AG5wANnwgkIHwAtgBG0MgAPsisUKDSUaYQKp4MwAAmtvRMrMihJG48-ILCouaSMnLI8kFhEdGx8YnkkMokLeoeWjp6BsZJ5ZaVNrRY9uDQ8EjIAMLuuHgAnhBSgSHhUAA0yMFMYAAWa3VbyOlqAPxHG9v7DLrMlwbr0NvBoHyQD1cvMRCMIOkvk9jq8gbUNik0plRv9cggSHMigIhCJ9IMrFUas8TuCfrioOdtvjCcCNiTiUTsec2kl5shurp9IYTB10cMsuNHFMUKQ6YQSKkMtQFt4-AFSfUYmA4iAEtEOpChR4lisoN8TrtwIcJSczpBHvibncoGDsa93p8DWbfv9AVaQTtTcdFdC6GBFgAHHlqGYMYIepgQcDMZA8JSJLHHRKNWXNNSKCOGnWU47kqkpskZ6Bp1OKaiwtjpdqh3jI0poiwY9o+v0BwzBlQdOkM3rMgaV9m0IA)

Any idea to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Type assertions are the simplest solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The underlying cause is that TypeScript does not support resolving a call to an overloaded function/constructor with multiple of its call/construct signatures at once.  The call `new Date(...args);` is a single call but in order for it to be accepted, the compiler would have to break `DateComponents` up into its union members and see that each member is assignable to at least one construct signature.  Instead, it sees that no single `Date` construct signature is applicable for the entire `DateComponents` union, and gives up.

Note that the specific wording of the error you're seeing is kind of a red herring; the compiler can't accept the input and tries to shoehorn this into the available error message about number of parameters.  This has happened before (e.g., [microsoft/TypeScript#28010](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28010), [microsoft/TypeScript#20372](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20372)), but it hasn't seemed like a big priority to fix.

Anyway, there is a (rather longstanding) open feature request in GitHub asking for overloaded functions to accept unions of parameters; see [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107). It's not clear that this will ever happen.

---

So, what can you do?  The easiest thing is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const d: D = function (...args: DateComponents): Date {
  return new Date(...args as ConstructorParameters<typeof Date>);
}
```

I know you want something "prettier", but believe me, anything I can think of to fix it turns out to be uglier.

---

For example, you can walk the compiler through the different possibilities manually and put a bunch of redundant code in there:

```
const e: D = function (...args: DateComponents): Date {
  return args.length === 0 ? new Date(...args) :
    args.length === 1 ? new Date(...args) :
      new Date(...args);
}
```

which is not pretty either.

---

Or you can try to build some code that converts an overloaded constructor into a non-overloaded one that takes a union type of parameters.  That is, [manually simulate an implementation of microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-723611576).  If you did this, the call would look like this:

```
const f: D = function (...args: DateComponents): Date {
  return new (unifyConstructorOverloads(Date))(...args);
}
```

which is not that ugly itself.  But the definition of `unifyConstructorOverloads` would be like this:

```
type UnifyConstructorOverloads<T extends new (...args: any) => any> =
  new (...args: ConstructorParameters<ConstructorOverloads<T>[number]>) =>
    InstanceType<ConstructorOverloads<T>[number]>;

const unifyConstructorOverloads = <T extends new (...args: any) => any>(f: T) => f as
  UnifyConstructorOverloads<T>;
```

which is getting homelier, uses a type assertion, and depends on a definition of `ConstructorOverloads<T>`, a hypothetical type function that takes an overloaded constructor and separates its multiple construct signatures into a tuple.  There's no programmatic way to do this as far as I can tell, so you have to simulate that too up to some number of overloads (say, 5):

```
type ConstructorOverloads<T> =
  T extends {
    new(...args: infer A1): infer R1; new(...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    new(...args: infer A3): infer R3; new(...args: infer A4): infer R4;
    new(...args: infer A5): infer R5;
  } ? [
    new (...args: A1) => R1, new (...args: A2) => R2,
    new (...args: A3) => R3, new (...args: A4) => R4,
    new (...args: A5) => R5
  ] : T extends {
    new(...args: infer A1): infer R1; new(...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    new(...args: infer A3): infer R3; new(...args: infer A4): infer R4
  } ? [
    new (...args: A1) => R1, new (...args: A2) => R2,
    new (...args: A3) => R3, new (...args: A4) => R4
  ] : T extends {
    new(...args: infer A1): infer R1; new(...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    new(...args: infer A3): infer R3
  } ? [
    new (...args: A1) => R1, new (...args: A2) => R2,
    new (...args: A3) => R3
  ] : T extends {
    new(...args: infer A1): infer R1; new(...args: infer A2): infer R2
  } ? [
    new (...args: A1) => R1, new (...args: A2) => R2
  ] : T extends {
    new(...args: infer A1): infer R1
  } ? [
    new (...args: A1) => R1
  ] : any
```

which, as far as aesthetics go, is well past "ugly" and probably hovering around "grotesque".  If you were going to do this sort of overload-unification thing in many places in your code base, I could imagine shutting away `ConstructorOverloads` (and an analogous `Overloads` for regular functions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options) for that code) into an unlit library, so that you could use it without ever looking directly upon its abominable visage.

---

But if you're only doing it a few times, I'd strongly suggest using a type assertion and moving on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIBQCUAXMgCJyQDcWAvlggPYgDOYycJ6AvMjAK4gEYYE3wA6CXCgBzZiQDaAXWJkKKbLigQwfKCGQgIAd1WQ8EsVNkFqdLKEixEKAEKYc+AG5wANnwgkIHwAtgBG0MgAPsisUKDSUaYQKp4MwAAmtvRMrMihJG48-ILCouaSMnLI8kFhEdGx8YnkkMokLeoeWjp6BsZJ5ZaVNrRY9uDQ8EjIAMLuuHgAnhBSgSHhUAA0yMFMYAAWa3VbyOlqAPxHG9v7DLrMlwbr0NvBoHyQD1cvMRCMIOkvk9jq8gbUNik0plRv9cggSHMigIhCJ9IMrFUas8TuCfrioOdtvjCcCNiTiUTsec2kl5shurp9IYTB10cMsuNHFMUKQ6YQSKkMtQFt4-AFSfUYmA4iAEtEOpChR4lisoN8TrtwIcJSczpBHvibncoGDsa93p8DWbfv9AVaQTtTcdFdC6GBFgAHHlqGYMYIepgQcDMZA8JSJLHHRKNWXNNSKCOGnWU47kqkpskZ6Bp1OKaiwtjpdqh3jI0poiwY9o+v0BwzBlQdOkM3rMgaVyrsEO+ljSvhCBhQAAKUjgwW00GYAB53V6GDAkgA+EZ2AvIcW8pElVHiCqyauQX3+wMNg+dTTaRnsSpiHxB6QHUNcHgABmQ5z6LLUbOsyCIHlwDFb3vR9nx4ABGd9P3bPdmAIP8ANwaDWQ7awOTXGBiy3FEylQqoOiPOsgzAOCz2bS9W36PABGAGBFh7WJ+zAQcAHlPGgHwGDgQE8AVAgfzgjkxlnFAGL7AcoDYjiuMBKcABVF1DDw5PXAAPSAARDDQkOZASSFAGAIlQcCVAMiIACVwMoT89OQMyoDQAAmUyQEMhzzMc4UdOMWz7LQABmFy3OQcz-Os3S8P01yjIAFiCiyYq83AItgqLgtQABWeL3IyryaCg+RELbWzjPgrhFMsokqMipyyoqxzNiK6rUoCuqQv8qqTBKuLQwqmLGqQ6CSqy3qQoyjwExIFSIHUoNATpZKfJqvzSrSiyrJs5booc1BnLW9zPKaoxfO21r9va8Klpala4vO8yYo8fKP0Kwbipq0rRsqob3ucz6GqO3chn3VrPo676WtQHrypCmLkAmv9kGm2bNIWzbrtO1a7NOyzLuOrb0r2rHgo8pK0aBqoVsCu7-MegqAZKkzPvAzrAarWq-oG7yuvewLQfhqa1I0+btMWvH0fSky7o2lLyfO3bspCxzaee+n3sZ6GvreiHfo1pXcEmxHBbmrSjpOiWFcs5XqlViH1Yq8D+fYEBFmEz0UAAVRAWj6JycTmMk9ioE47jpyRoWQy12WncWNq4GdxSuA8SO2bEqAmMHEcoDHCcTSnVP04D6SQ-kxdIw2RRl16xCAElezjpA5LdvPfbTiSpKDmTQ9L-EK+obJe2QGi6PztvA+D+aeHko2UeTyoSDjmPRoXxc8EwxG2oXOBmA8T3vZH-32-Hru+6AA)

Comment: Thanks jcalz for your great answer. The misleading error message made me think that a simple solution was possible. I'm going to use type assertion since the alternative is ... as you said ... grotesque :)