# Type inference of overloaded function

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an instance of the following class:

```
// Interface from library
interface EventEmitter {
  on(eventName: 'click', handler: () => void): void
  on(eventName: 'change', handler: (newVal: string) => void): void
  // much more events
}
```

I want to convert this event subscription to rxjs observables in a generic way:

```
class EventHolder {
  click$ = this.fromEvent('click')
  change$ = this.fromEvent('change')

  private emitter

  constructor(instance: EventEmitter) {
    this.emitter = instance
  }

  // here we lose the type
  private fromEvent<E, T>(eventName: E): Observable<T> {
    // No overload matches this call.
    return new Observable<T>(o => this.emitter.on(eventName, o.next))
  }
}
```

But this does not work, because typescript can not infer the type of E.
Is there a nice way to write this `fromEvent` function and keep the type safety?

Currently I do the following:

```
class EventHolder {
  click$ = this.fromClickEvent()
  change$ = this.fromChangeEvent()

  private emitter

  constructor(instance: EventEmitter) {
    this.emitter = instance
  }

  private fromClickEvent(): Observable<void> {
    return new Observable<void>(o => this.emitter.on('click', o.next))
  }

  private fromChangeEvent(): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>(o => this.emitter.on('change', o.next))
  }
}
```

Is there a nicer way with less repeating code?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) don't really provide a way to extract the information you want in a type safe way... at least not one that isn't tedious to use (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options/59538756#59538756) for a crazy solution to pull out the call signatures from an overloaded function; it definitely doesn't scale).  There is an open issue, at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-723611576) asking for some way to collapse overloads into a single call signature, but it's not part of the language today.

It would have been better for `EventEmitter`'s `on` method to be a generic method looking like this:

```
type EventMap = {
    click: void;
    change: string;
    // much more events
}
interface BetterEventEmitter {
  on<E extends keyof EventMap>(eventName: E, handler: (newVal: EventMap[E]) => void): void;
}
```

Here you see that the `EventMap` type maps `eventName` to the type of the argument expected by the `handler` callback.  Again, if there were some principled way to manipulate overloads programmatically, you could probably derive `EventMap` from the existing `EventEmitter` like this:

```
type EventMap = _EM<Omit<OverloadedParameters<EventEmitter['on']>, keyof any[]>>
type _EM<T extends Record<keyof T, [string, (...args: any) => void]>> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K][0]]: [...Parameters<T[K][1]>, void][0]
}
```

but since there's no scalable `OverloadedParameters<>` type function to use, you might as well just write out `EventMap` by yourself.

Armed with *this* version of `EventEmitter`, you could write the `fromEvent()` in a straightforward way:

```
class EventHolder {
  click$ = this.fromEvent('click')
  change$ = this.fromEvent('change')

  private emitter

  constructor(instance: BetterEventEmitter) {
    this.emitter = instance
  }

  private fromEvent<E extends keyof EventMap>(eventName: E) {
    return new Observable<EventMap[E]>((o: Subscriber<EventMap[E]>) =>
      this.emitter.on(eventName, o.next))
  }
}
```

Great, but again, you have to write out `EventMap` by hand.

---

The only consolation I can think of, other than asking whoever wrote the library with the huge list of overloads to change their method to the generic version, is that you can at least detect if your `EventMap` is incorrect in some way:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
type AlsoEventEmitter = UnionToIntersection<{ [K in keyof EventMap]: {
  on(eventName: K, handler: (newVal: EventMap[K]) => void): void
} }[keyof EventMap]>
type AcceptableEventEmitter<
  T extends EventEmitter = AlsoEventEmitter,
  // error here? --------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  U extends AlsoEventEmitter = EventEmitter
  // error here? ------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  > = void;
// errors above indicate a problem with EventMap
```

The `AlsoEventEmitter` type is a synthesized list of overloads, which you can compare directly against `EventEmitter`.  (You can't programmatically *read* a list of overloads but you *can* produce one).  If a property from `EventMap` is missing/extra/incorrect, you should get at least one error above telling you the issue.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo4BlAVwwGMphVs4BfOAMyghDgHIoAPAFboeAbgBQk4ADsY2NnhqY4AURyZZKkMBhyoicXDgRpACkzrZAOTwhMALl41CwGgGseZABZ5pAE2IoR1MASjgAXgA+OBwIYD8Qx1j4w2MzCw0YGztHHhofaQBzTE84AoDsYOlMAHcANTxCR3QYeiKwqJi4hKTu1IB6frgQSnzh6GUM2XRxZkl+gCoYAE8wZTVMgFk8MAi4AH0VTYAeZG0YU-UoQgg8P0w-AAU8KFtMPXRjjc1zvQBtHgmHgAXUiZDcmGWEDYcF8yz+oMi4hWawOR2OABU4Jh+HJ-Og4AAlTA0aB+Y4QqEwjFkP4tNqFMimAB0rJehXQjjhHWiyT8iL2CFSfwA0nAZHBKdC4Fi8ASMaLgX8AAzA4GOP6s5nPV52D6YxV-ACMoLIfKVqtmC36khR60sMG2u3CBiMzlcbl68QkboKxWarRkhR9cEGw1GXnGUEmDpmcxkegUSjgACF3npvjAtDo9K60l9sbiNH4CVKYZmnZFzA7sg5VN5fBUgnBTNV6o1HBWdn8VMCeV14okB34JHNkatlABVaTAEwYiAASVk2CwNBgs+kx0n0XCqVMk8LeJLsOkyzgAH4W564JP+3y4I5qlcwjijwTTKZrzI2EwF3fumEl4Lg+cBPtgEh2nAACChDoBAmbZroTAutOG7zkuHwkuuJjHEgoritIkqQtKXZgOqeYmNWmS1o4IoNv4gRVLUDRNKoDpOoq-6Dl6fizCwfxlmxWw7KC46olBNBKGAMAEMQCG-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-a5yPGeO7vDul29W+V9XnTB6kbeOB3b4a-v2++wPy9m6Hc-L4fr8O2vKez73O8a5GjrqPSuRdL4-1bu3NWXd-6gPnv3I2r8jS-w3qfD+gDL4oKgVyU8MtUTIHlrce4TwXhvH1MrCIqRCHYAViWTE0RoYEl9sgC8qQ8JiglIJZA5EdTkJXF8XErw1ynEVCAjO3Ji5wkiNEVgj4MhHTEsoGh1xiEPGJBjLGGIJwMKoUYFRdClaMM7seFhbCjAcIIkRKkKByIaMxtIbRaxBGtEUBcZAYjH4F0kZ0aRsiQJgSgEAA)

Comment: Cool solution! Can we use it when there is an event with two or more params. E.g. `on(eventName: 'click', handler: (x: number, y: number) => void): void`. Just an example. I'll ask the author to use only one event-object-param per event and to switch to your generic solution.