# typescript mapped types with overload functions

Tags: typescript, types

I want to define a type from a interface where I change the return type to Promise of the callback return value and get the function parameters from the original definition.

```
// original
SET(key: string, value: string, cb?: Callback<'OK'>): R;

// wanted
SET(key: string, value: string): Promise<'OK'>
```

My biggest problem is that the Commands interface has a lot of overload functions and the mapped types functionality only keep the last one (overwriting the others):

```
set(key: string, value: string, cb?: Callback<'OK'>): R;
set(key: string, value: string, flag: string, cb?: Callback<'OK'>): R;
set(key: string, value: string, mode: string, duration: number, cb?: Callback<'OK' | undefined>): R;
set(key: string, value: string, mode: string, duration: number, flag: string, cb?: Callback<'OK' | undefined>): R;
set(key: string, value: string, flag: string, mode: string, duration: number, cb?: Callback<'OK' | undefined>): R;
SET(key: string, value: string, cb?: Callback<'OK'>): R;
SET(key: string, value: string, flag: string, cb?: Callback<'OK'>): R;
SET(key: string, value: string, mode: string, duration: number, cb?: Callback<'OK' | undefined>): R;
SET(key: string, value: string, mode: string, duration: number, flag: string, cb?: Callback<'OK' | undefined>): R;
SET(key: string, value: string, flag: string, mode: string, duration: number, cb?: Callback<'OK' | undefined>): R;
```

I currently build up a mapped type, which keeps only the last overload version with to much required types. That's currently my main problem. Also the Return value is not that one I want to have and the Parameters still has the cb function in it, but maybe I will find a solutions for this, but I couldn't find a solution to keep all overloaded function.

```
// current implementation
type PromisedCommands = {
    [X in keyof Commands<boolean>]: (...args: Parameters<Commands<boolean>[X]>) => Promise<ReturnType<Commands<boolean>[X]>>
}
```

The commands interface has much  more the 100 items, so it isn't an options to write them by my own and keep track of changes.

How could I keep the overload functions or change the parameters of Command functions and the return type to the callback type?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] that can be used to demonstrate the issue in a standalone IDE?  I don't know what `R` or `Callback` is, nor are these quite well-formed method declarations.  There really is no great way to manipulate function types with multiple call signatures (although there are some [not great ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218)), so ideally you'd refactor to avoid overloads.  But without a [mcve] I'm not sure how best to do that.

Comment: Also see [microsoft/TypeScript#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732)

Comment: I just made some guesses and can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkv20m)... does that work for your needs?  If not, please elaborate, preferably with a [mcve] to demonstrate.  If it does work, I'd be happy to write up an answer; let me know.

Comment: Sooo nice, thank you very much, I still try to understand what you did, but I extend your example and changed some values closer to what is defined for redis (sorry that I missed the code example) it seem to work, but I copied it to my project and it shows for the get unknown (return and parameter type) but much closer then before and in the changed example it works: [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2OlN)

Comment: in my project it seem to create a overload for the get function, one with unknown and one with string. Last one is the correct one, in the playground it have only the version with string. But I am still try to unterstand the type definitions

Comment: I add some more spezial types, but in the playground it seem to be still ok: [link](https://tsplay.dev/WP5Aew), but at least I am not sure if it this is defined as expacted. The stuff comes from [types/redis](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redis/index.d.ts)

Comment: This feels like scope creep to me; I'm willing to be convinced otherwise, but I don't see how this issue in the last link "`promisedCommands.geoadd() // should not allow empty`" has anything to do with the question as asked; `geoadd()` has an overload like  `(...args: Array<string | T | Callback<U>>): R;`, and that one is essentially unchanged, so you can call it with no arguments.  I'm happy to write up how the code I originally wrote works, and mention that there are caveats (since the overload manipulation is fragile).  Would you want such an answer?  Or has the scope widened since then?

Comment: Sorry forget the comment „//should not allow empty“, the original type file also allow an empty value, so it is wrong it should changed in this type file and is not relevant for this implementation. Your result is nice, I am just searching a solution for the unknown problem I have in my local environment. I think it relates to the `tubleToOverload` Type.

Comment: I did a little bit more research to find the unknwon problem in my local environment and reproduce it  in ts playground: [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6RoN) if you are interested. The problem seems to be that `OverloadToTuple<T>` matched at the first statement if  `strictFunctionTypes` is not set to true. Now it works for me also in my project, thank you very much, without you I wouldn't get to this point