# How to handle function overload in generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My goal is to make an another type as proxy which simply remaps method `bar` to method `foo` of original object. I want to ensure that `bar` method will have same call signature as `foo`.

The code which I wrote works nicely when there are no overloads for method `foo` but does not work with overloads.

```js
class Some {
    foo(val: 1): void;
    foo(val: 2): void;
    foo(val: number) {
        console.log(val);
    }
}

class Translator<T extends { foo: (...args: any) => any }> {
    obj: T;
    constructor(obj: T) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    bar(...params: Parameters<T["foo"]>): void;

    bar(...args: any[]) {
        this.obj.foo(...args);
    }
}

const s = new Some();
s.foo(1);
s.foo(2);

// @ts-expect-error
s.foo(3);

const t = new Translator(s);

t.bar(1); // should be accepted by TS but it is not
t.bar(2);

// @ts-expect-error
t.bar(3); // must fail
```

Comment: "Override" is not the term you're looking for; you should change it to "overload" instead.  In `class A {foo() {console.log("A");}}  class B extends A {foo() {console.log("B");}}`, we are *overriding* `foo`.  There are two methods named `foo` and `new B().foo()` calls a different one from `new A().foo()`.  On the other hand in `function bar(): void; function bar(x: string): void; function bar(x?: string) {console.log(x)}` we are *overloading* `bar`.  There are two ways to call it but there is just one `bar()` implementation. When we call `bar()` or `bar("x")` we are calling the same function.

Comment: Yeah, this is a [known limitation on inference with overloads](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24275#issuecomment-390701982).  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgL8BN) workaround work for you?  Instead of saying that `bar` takes the same parameters as `foo`, we are saying that `bar` has the same type as `foo`.  If you really want to try to play with overload parameters, you could do what I did [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218), but it's probably not worth it.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @jcalz sadly I need to change return type. So I can not use it. But it is good to know that this approach is currently impossible.

Comment: So, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd48QN) work for you?  It only works for some fixed maximum number of overloads, and for non-overloads it's a lot of unnecessary complication.   Let me know what you think.

Comment: @jcalz I needed proxy for typed event emitter, I borrowed pattern [here](https://rjzaworski.com/2019/10/event-emitters-in-typescript). That is the reason why I can not use the second solution, because number of overrides can be huge. I solved this problem by creating proxy which accept the same parameter as "typed event emitter" - EventMap, so sadly it is not usable generally and also not elegant, but at least it seems that it sofar covers my usecase [example](https://tsplay.dev/WPjKqN)