# Built-in `Parameters` helper type doesn't work for method overloading

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Sometimes I use `Parameters` type helper to extract (infer) the function arguments to reuse them in code (*if the library doesn't explicitly exports the types*). It works well for simple method, but fails for methods with the overloads. Consider this example:

```
class Foo {
    foo(a: number)
    foo(a: string)
    foo(mix: number | string) {
        return mix;
    }
}

type FooParameters = Parameters<Foo['foo']>;

function wrapper(...args: FooParameters) {

}

wrapper(1);
```

[TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNEAowC5oA7AVwFsAjAUwCcBKQsIgT2nS1wOggBcaBLIgHMG0Jq3bZ4OMvwAehUpVrQAPtz6CRKdhhpUeJGkWiy5AbnYBfVDdQ9mABypxEABTA0wZA7RgBeaA8vHx4-AB4EeABtAHIpWIBdAD5LVEwSImAefngTAHcvR2caHAA6Cs8hCEIo4O9fGgg6HVtUVEKwYtocAEY6cyA)

The `FooParameters` type here is `[a: string]` - that's why the wrapper method from the example fails to accept `number`.

Is there another way to extract full arguments types and reuse them?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m3zebN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos. Also note that `[mix: number | string]` is not one of the call signatures of `Foo["foo"]`.  If you write `new Foo().foo(Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : 1)` you get a compiler error, and it would be weird for `wrapper()` to accept `number | string` when `Foo["foo"]` does not.

Comment: That doesn't solve your problem, by the way. Presumably you do want `wrapper()` to accept either `number` or `string` just like `Foo["foo"]`, but you should probably fix up the question and code to be free of mistakes so that it's clear what you want.

Comment: Ah, one more thing, you are talking about [*overloading*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) (a single function/method with multiple call signatures) and not [*overriding*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#overriding-methods) (a subclass providing its own implementation of a method from the superclass).   So you should probably also edit that.

Comment: @jcalz , thank you so much for your time in clearing this up. Indeed I've meant `overloading`. And my bad, indeed this question was already raised in: [parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options)