# Typescript Wrap Overloaded Function Generically with Optional Parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to wrap an overloaded function (from a package I did not write, so I cannot edit the overload declarations) and retain the original parameters and return types of the function. Typescript seems to only pick up the last declared overload function when deciding how to type the wrapper.

Does anyone know of a way to generically wrap an overloaded function and retain typings of *all* overloads? It would be nice if we could have a `Partial<Tuple>`

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAKogUwA8oCwATAZ0QAoA6B9VAc0oC5F0wBPAbQF0AlIgC8APk48xNALAAoRImBgOuADTzFaLJgKoONZarWIGdJqw4AFJugC2BUqkp4xw8YgBKjkKjC5uXVd5YQBvTURUHz9aMwt2RBsMBycXXDdRCW1MXVRDMBM4lkpBeQBfeXlyAggAGyYCJXBoeCQagAs4GlISDkooVBgwZkEOADc4GHIqmvqopshYBEIITu7iKD6BoeYTOEwlsATQstHECanKuQgEfpXOgHUMHIJyURRnmg64E3yTHqg7gk4QUkWiSGU6xIpTkpyu3yeOleNAA5O0CLVanAUTCgA)

```
function wrap<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  fn: T,
  wrapper: (fn: T, ...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>
) {
  return (...args: Parameters<T>) => wrapper(fn, ...args)
}

declare function echo(text: string): void
declare function echo(text: string, options: {}): void

const echoWrapped = wrap(echo, (fn, text) => {
  return fn(text)
})

echoWrapped('hello') // error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

Comment: This is sounding like higher-kinded types, which aren't a TS feature (yet, at least), but... to make sure that any answerers address the real details of your problem: Is that the actual overloaded function? If not, will you please update your question to include the real case? Here's how you can solve the current question: https://tsplay.dev/WyboJw

Comment: There's no good way to manipulate overloaded function types at the type level; you can [sort of do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218) for some fixed maximum number of overloads, but it's yucky.  Essentially it's a TS design limitation, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43731 among others.  I can write up an answer if you want, but mostly the suggestion here is "don't use overloads for this sort of thing".

Comment: If you're willing to [annotate your callback parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) then the compiler *can* pick the right overload, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nabvom).  Does that approach work for your needs?