# How to merge type signatures with type properties

Tags: typescript

How does one merge types that have both call signatures and properties, without resorting to the intersection `&`?  Intersection `&` creates types that are shown as e.g. `Foo & { a: string } & { ()=>void } & Bar` which may be hard to understand and abstract.  When what one wants is `{()=>void, a: string, b: string, c: number }` which can be simpler to parse.

```js
type Merge<T1, T2> = {
  [k in keyof T1 | keyof T2]: k extends keyof T1 ? T1[k] : k extends keyof T2 ? T2[k] : never;
}

type Foo = {
    (a: string): number;
    (a: number): number;
    foo1: string
}

type Bar = {
    bar1: number
}

type FooBar = Merge<Foo, Bar> // Merge excluding the call signatures - how does one include the call signatures?
/* end type should be:
type FooBar = {
    (a: string): number;
    (a: number): number;
    foo1: string
    bar1: number
}
and not be an intersection `Foo & Bar`
*/
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwDwBUCMAaK6BMAfFALxQDeAsAFBRQDaA1lAnFIxCEgGZ6ZQAfdpx558AXQBc7KBAAewCHAAmAZ2FdeWKAH4+TcVGnN5ileo6axusQaNQ4EAG4QATgG4aAXxo1QkKAApAFdVYABlBABzOABDYGDXCFUMYhIaOnRZBSU1CigACgA6EtjXKNVpVm43KABBTABKKrga1ygAJUx3QpKisoqWtvr8ZpZW2o78HuLS8srx4bqAZjHqyeWZvoGF9fa6gBY1ifaOg6gvXQyKa7pZ-vnpBrGurbnBkZfp3veFlZfNj8Hh9Di8DtdLpJrllTLl1OQgTshrVnsjTt1EY9FijRmjOt97kjsftVniOssLldaDdqXdtljUZ0MYSGbj8W9gX9SZ1lhCjNDsmY8giWR89vUmmTmfSxSdPmT8JSdNcqLTMSDJUyOUS6mypnyodSYTlzPlRbs5Yzxa8lSrbuq-prXgbro4XB5fNR-NAAGJIJCkGl0O6xaRhVysKJjODBAC2ACM3J41QVQw444nXNGM0n7dx-Zgw8AI3Aot5Pd6oAAhMqB1XBqDxsqF9MJtzl6h+cC+-019pkeDINB+pC4PvEAD0E6gwUQKGyAGMADbBZSRqDAAAW0AXsSXS6gqmicQSSXUAFooJukAB3KDKJDJKAoaCsZer6Bbnd7g9HmLxRJkmVagJwAKlkFQN27Q9r2CJdlEbCBDUrEc+zre1UyLEso2kGM2w9FM0zwzNs3w5MG3zJAW3DSN7SbVwW2I9tqB8ahQInIA)

Comment: It looks to me like you actually want an intersection instead of a union. See this [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8ERVN)

Comment: I started with intersections, but they suck as they split my definitions and make it hard to understand complex built up types `{ ..} & {.. } & {...} & {...}`.  So I've been using unions which work much better, but now I have a problem merging call signatures.

Comment: The way you defined the `Union` type is actually an **intersection** and not a union because it merges two types. A union does not merge two types and instead combines them with a logical OR. I don't really get your point about *"split my definitions"* and *"hard to understand complex types"*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thank Tobias, if one hovers over your playground link type FooBar it appears as Foo & Bar.  If you construct a type out of multiple sub types then one ends up with something that shows up as `Foo & Bar *& ... & .... ` which if the type is long is confusing and complex to parse - and not a good experience.  Better to just show the much simpler intersection as you've called it.

Comment: [In this example](https://tsplay.dev/w2PV8m) if you hover over the Example type you will see how `&` can quickly become very confusing.

Comment: What you're asking for is currently impossible if you add the requirement that "intersections are forbidden".  You can't manipulate call signatures with mapped types (seems like [ms/TS#29261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29261) is the closest thing to a feature request).  You can't programmatically generate call signatures inside other types.  You could maybe write something that works up to a fixed number of call signatures, but it would be a horrible type function.

Comment: Please either accept the "use an intersection" answer, or [edit] the question to explicitly forbid intersections, at which point I could possibly write up an answer that says "no, sorry" and points to ms/TS#29261.

Comment: Also, please consider changing the name `Union` to something like `Merge`, since it is not a union.

Comment: @jcalz: thanks I've changed it toe `Merge`

Comment: @jcalz for your answer - I think that is the right answer.  Expanding mapped types to be able to map in call signatures would be a useful feature.

Comment: Note that right now your only mention of intersections appears to be in a code comment.  Could you put that clearly in the question?

Comment: @jcalz - question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently (TS4.7) no way to do this programmatically without using [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) do not preserve [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures); there is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#29261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29261) asking for some way to do this (well, it technically asks about [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), but [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29261#issuecomment-451536491) mentions pulling signatures out of a type).

You could *try* to do this by making the intersection and then teasing out the resulting multiple call signatures (i.e., [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)), but unfortunately there is no good programmatic way to do this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218) for more information.  Even if you could do this you'd probably have to resort to intersections to combine them again.

For now, I'd say that intersection types are the best you can do.