# Copy overloads from class constructor to method

Tags: typescript, class, oop, overloading

Given this class where the constructor has 2 overloads

```
export class Span {
  start: Time
  end: Time
  constructor (span: TimeConstructable, end?: TimeConstructable)
  constructor (span: {
    start: TimeConstructable,
    end: TimeConstructable
  })
  constructor (span: {
    start: TimeConstructable,
    end: TimeConstructable
  } | TimeConstructable, end?: TimeConstructable) {
    if (typeof span === 'object' && ('start' in span) && ('end' in span)) {
      this.start = Time.m(span.start)
      this.end = Time.m(span.end)
    } else {
      if (!end) throw new Error('missing end in span')
      this.start = Time.m(span)
      this.end = Time.m(end)
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to add a new static method `Span.make` that also takes the same parameters and simply runs `new Span` with the arguments. I'd like to do this with repeating the code in the constructor.

I was asked to provide example

```
export class Span {
  start: Time
  end: Time
  constructor (span: TimeConstructable, end?: TimeConstructable)
  constructor (span: {
    start: TimeConstructable,
    end: TimeConstructable
  })
  constructor (span: {
    start: TimeConstructable,
    end: TimeConstructable
  } | TimeConstructable, end?: TimeConstructable) {
    if (typeof span === 'object' && ('start' in span) && ('end' in span)) {
      this.start = Time.m(span.start)
      this.end = Time.m(span.end)
    } else {
      if (!end) throw new Error('missing end in span')
      this.start = Time.m(span)
      this.end = Time.m(end)
    }
  }

  static make (span: TimeConstructable, end?: TimeConstructable)
  static make (span: {
    start: TimeConstructable,
    end: TimeConstructable
  })
  static make (span: {
    start: TimeConstructable,
    end: TimeConstructable
  } | TimeConstructable, end?: TimeConstructable) {
    return new Span(span, end)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you expect. It is not clear, at least for me

Comment: Please modify this code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  There should be no unimported/undefined/undeclared types/values.  I don't know what `Time` and `TimeConstructable` are, and neither does my IDE.  Ideally you would replace such external types/values with simpler built-in things, but barring that you should at least provide their definitions.   Also, you say "I'd like to do this **with** repeating the code in the constructor."... is that a typo?

Comment: Note that, as per [my answer to one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/2887218) there's no programmatic way to manipulate overload signatures... at least not one that isn't more work than just copying the signature manually, if you're only going to do it once.  Overloads are best avoided and can usually be replaced with unions of rest tuples.  If I see a [mre] here I can give suggestions.

Comment: For example, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdYAym) might work for you.  If so, please let me know (and I'd appreciate if you @jcalz mention me, otherwise I might not be notified) and either I or you could [edit] the question code to use `number` instead of your `Time`-related version.