# Obtain the union of parameter types for an arbitrary overload?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/5583443 shows a way to obtain the union of the parameter types of an overloaded function, up to a certain fixed number of overloads (set by how long you want to make the definition of `Overloads<T>`). With things like recursive conditional types in more recent versions of TypeScipt, is it now possible to write this so that you can nominally infer the union of the parameter types of an arbitrary overload (subject to processing power limitations in the compiler, of course)?

Is the situation the same or different for types which are the intersection of multiple function types? (I can't quite get clear on whether the type of an overloaded function is or is not precisely the same type as the intersection of the function types of each overload...)

Comment: Nope, it's still not possible, even in 2022. You can't use `infer` to "single out" an overload; you always get the first. I'd suspect jcalz would update that answer if it was possible. And also, I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: As far as I know it's still not possible; you can use `infer` to grab the last call signature, but you can't *exclude* a call signature in order to do things recursively.  It's as if you could take `[1,2,3,4]` and get `4`, but you have no way of getting `[1,2,3]` from it.