# Typescript typeof overloaded function distinction problem

Tags: typescript

I am now currently working on a project which uses Mongoose and I attemped to use `Parameters<type>`
which is one of the Utility Types.

When I attempted to get the type of a parameter of the function which is overloaded, I could only get the function that I did not want to get - in my case I attempted to get that of `mongoose.Model.find` [Ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find). It returned callback function instead of `FilterQuery<type>`

To understand better:

[image: Type of find]

When I request by `Parameters<typeof FooModel>`,
4 Functions overloaded, I want to have 3rd function, but 4th function comes up

There's already an issue for this problem, and it seems not to be solved yet "officially"

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

Do you have any ideas or even practices for this problem?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) and consider providing a self-contained [mre] that can be pasted into a standalone IDE that demonstrates your issue without needing private or third-party libraries.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59535995/2887218) but without a [mre] I'm not sure.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your response
Yeah obviously I should've provided a minimal example but your response is already sufficient for me
thanks

Comment: I think there's not a feature yet that can satisfy me