# How to make a generic function returning a promise with event arguments?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a non-generic function that waits for an "`EventEmitter`" (not really since I need to use it on other classes that have `once` but don't extend `EventEmitter`):

```
export function waitEvent(emitter: { once: Function }, event: string): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        emitter.once(event, (...args: any[]) => {
            resolve(args);
        });
    });
}
```

How do I make it generic?

For example, imagine Typescript knows that variable `page` can emit an event `loaded` with args `(title: string)`. How do I make it so for code `const [title] = await waitEvent(page, 'loaded')` it knows that `title` will be a `string`?

Here's a real world example:

```
import {chromium} from "playwright";
const browser = await chromium.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.once('popup', async (page) => {
    await page.click('h1');
});
const [popup] = await waitEvent(page, 'popup');
await popup.click('h1');
```

The usage in the regular `.once` call knows page is a `Page`, the one after the `waitEvent` thinks `any` with my original version, and `Worker` with @jcalz's approach, so the second call to `.click` doesn't work.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrXz3W) what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  It would help if you provide a definition of `page` since it's not obvious how this will work if `once()` is overloaded or generic, which I imagine it will be.  Anyway, let me know (and mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me).

Comment: Like, if it's generic, then `waitEvent` probably needs to know the type of the event emitter, and then you could, maybe, write it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMBglW)?  So a bit more of the use case would be helpful here.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks mate, the first approach is what I was looking for

Comment: @jcalz, sorry I was too quick to judge. It doesn't appear to work correctly, here's an example: https://i.imgur.com/fTqbT1k.png I'll update the q to have this code

Comment: Could you please provide this code as a self-contained example without reliance on third-party libraries?  I don't know anything about `playwright` and if I have to start looking through third-party docs in order to understand the types it's quite a digression.  Maybe you could make a toy version with a few possible event types?

Comment: Starting to slog through that code, the problem here is that `once` is [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), and TS doesn't handle type operations on overloads very well.  So you'd have to refactor and that's going to be ugly no matter what (unless you can get upstream changes to `playwright`).  A toy example would be helpful here to give you the flavor without the pain of rewriting  a zillion event types

Comment: @jcalz I tried making a toy example, but when I did, your code worked fine lol. I can't get upstream into playwright, so I'll just resort to `await waitEvent as [Page]`. Still your answers are nice as they handle simpler cases, so thank you for that

Comment: Sigh, fine, I'll do the ugly thing.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6v4ew) meet your needs?  Let me know and I'll write up the answer, unless I'm still missing something here.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I guess there is no way to do this TS declaration without needing to import stuff from playwright? If you could write an answer with your first approach and explain why it doesn't work with playwright without the other code from approach 3, that would be great

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive first-order call signature for `waitEvent()` looks like this:

```
declare function waitEvent<K extends string, A extends any[]>(emitter: {
    once(event: K, cb: (...args: A) => void): void
}, event: K): Promise<A>;
```

As long as you call `waitEvent()` on an emitter with a `once()` method of the right shape, the compiler should be able to infer `A` for you:

```
const thing = {
    once(event: "loaded", cb: (title: string) => void) { }
}
const [title] = await waitEvent(thing, "loaded");
title // string

const otherThing = {
    once(event: "exploded", cb: (blastRadius: number) => void) { }
}
const [rad] = await waitEvent(otherThing, "exploded");
rad // number
```

---

But unfortunately this will beak down in most real-world situations I can think of.  TypeScript doesn't have much support for expressing and manipulate higher order types.  In your case, the parameters of the `once(event, callback)` method of your event emitter probably can't be written with simple independent types like the `thing` and `otherThing` examples shown above.

Instead, they are correlated to each other.  So if `event` is, say, `"loaded"`, then `callback` is of type `(title: string) => void`.  But if `event` is something else (I will say, uh, `"exploded"`), then `callback` will be of some other type (say, `(blastRadius: number) => void`).  Meaning that the `thing` and `otherThing` examples would need to be combined into a single object that could deal with multiple ways of calling `once()`.

There are different ways to express such a relationship in TypeScript, and most of those ways are not conducive to type manipulation.  Traditionally, you would do this with an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with multiple call signatures:

```
interface MyEventEmitter {
    once(event: "loaded", cb: (title: string) => void): void;
    // ... more ... //
    once(event: "exploded", cb: (blastRadius: number) => void): void;
}
```

And this seems to be what the "playwright" library is doing.  That's great when you actually directly call `once()` on a value of type `MyEmitter`:

```
declare const emitter: MyEventEmitter;
emitter.once("loaded", title => title.toUpperCase()); // okay
emitter.once("exploded", rad => rad.toFixed(2)); // okay
```

But TypeScript cannot answer the question "if I call `once()` with an `event` argument of type `"loaded"`, what is the type of `cb`" unless *you actually call it directly*.  TypeScript cannot easily tell you the full relationship between `once()`'s `event` and the arg type of `cb`.

This is a design limitation, discussed at [microsoft/TypeScript#32164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164) (among other places).  Generally speaking, if you probe for the type of `once()`, such as using [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) on an overloaded function type, you will only get information about the last call signature:

```
type OnceParams = Parameters<MyEventEmitter['once']>;
// type OnceParams = [event: "exploded", cb: (blastRadius: number) => void]
// (where is the information abut the other call signatures)?
```

And so the above `waitEvent()` fails:

```
const [title] = await waitEvent(emitter, "loaded");
title // number ?!!?!
```

There are various questions about this and workarounds (see  [Parameters generic of overloaded function doesn't contain all options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59535995/2887218) for example) but none of them are pretty and they can only deal with some finite maximum number of call signatures.  If you're going to do that, you might want to just give up on having `emitter` be of an arbitrary type and instead hardcode `waitEvent()` for the actually expected type of `emitter`.

---

Another way of writing the above would be if `once()` were [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in some mapping interface like this:

```
 interface EventArgs {
    loaded: [title: string],
    exploded: [blastRadius: number]
}
interface MyEventEmitter {
    once<K extends keyof EventArgs>(event: K, cb: (...args: EventArgs[K]) => void): void;
}
```

Again, great when you actually directly call `once()` on a value of type `MyEmitter`:

```
declare const emitter: MyEventEmitter;
emitter.once("loaded", title => title.toUpperCase()); // okay
emitter.once("exploded", rad => rad.toFixed(2)); // okay
```

But TypeScript *still* cannot answer the question "if I call `once()` with an `event` argument of type `"loaded"`, what is the type of `cb`" unless *you actually call it directly*.

It's a slightly different limitation from the overloaded version; in this case maybe [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179) is a better source.  But it's the same basic problem; the function cannot easily be probed.

And so `waitEvent()` still does the wrong thing, albeit a slightly different wrong thing:

```
const [title] = await waitEvent(emitter, "loaded");
title // string | number (better, I guess?, but not great)
```

Here the compiler gives up and just infers `K` and `A` as their independent constraints for `EventEmitter`.

---

The only other way I could imagine representing this is with a rest parameter of a  [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
interface EventArgs {
    loaded: [title: string],
    exploded: [blastRadius: number]
}
type OnceArgs = { [K in keyof EventArgs]: 
  [event: K, cb: (...args: EventArgs[K]) => void] 
}[keyof EventArgs];
/* type OnceArgs = 
    [event: "loaded", cb: (title: string) => void] | 
    [event: "exploded", cb: (blastRadius: number) => void] 
*/
interface MyEventEmitter {
    once(...args: OnceArgs): void;
}
```

This sort of behaves like overloads, and are even shown in IntelliSense as overloads, but due to some limitations (see [microsoft/TypeScript#42987](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42987)) it isn't as nice to use:

```
declare const emitter: MyEventEmitter;
emitter.once("loaded", title => title.toUpperCase()); // error!
emitter.once("loaded", (title: string) => title.toUpperCase()) // okay
emitter.once("exploded", rad => rad.toFixed(2)); // error!
emitter.once("exploded", (rad: number) => rad.toFixed(2)); // okay

const [title] = await waitEventNaive(emitter, "loaded"); // error!!!
```

So that's probably a non-starter.  Still, this is at least *possible* to inspect it and rewrite `waitEvent` accordingly:

```
declare function waitEvent<
  A extends [string, (...args: any) => void], 
  K extends A[0]
>(emitter: {
    once(...args: A): void
}, event: K): Promise<Parameters<Extract<A, [K, any]>[1]>>;

const [title] = await waitEvent(emitter, "loaded");
title // string
const [rad] = await waitEvent(emitter, "exploded");
rad // number
```

Hooray, I guess.  But the chance that your third-party library will use this technique is low (maybe if it were easier to use?).

---

And that means probably what you should do is just figure out what type `emitter` is going to be, and write a targeted version of `waitEvent()` with a hardcoded relationship between the input and output types.  In the above example that would look like:

```
declare function waitEventHardCoded(
  emitter: MyEventEmitter, event: "loaded"): Promise<[title: string]>;
declare function waitEventHardCoded(
  emitter: MyEventEmitter, event: "exploded"): Promise<[blastRadius: number]>;
```

And then this would just work:

```
const [title] = await waitEventHardCoded(emitter, "loaded");
title.toUpperCase();
const [rad] = await waitEventHardCoded(emitter, "exploded");
rad.toFixed(2);
```

It's not satisfying, but it's what I'd do until and unless support for higher order function type manipulation in TypeScript improves significantly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHcosMBRANxFQwDljKAeAaXhAA8MrgBnebjGFlQBzADTwAgqw5deUVAE8A2gF0AfAAoQAWxKcYALngBvALAAoeFfh4wILZWpGm4sACMjGgHQ-Yw7kYSAJTwALxq8OQ4WMBBRlExFgC+4iCOGM5x8AAKMDi63CAMEmoA3BYWQvqIUHbwALIKFFRkuhj6JhbWNuj2aS1GAEQQOFCgwIOuHvAa2BgQIEb8giIh4ZHRsfGb5ZbWtn3pQ+wADiPjk-Dunm7Q-ABKY1jIAfCoyNpuIDBrEQlbGxiuySFXMoEgsAQKHQ2DwhGIZHSAAlYMAAMI4cZaNr6IyNZrUUg476pI7wYajC5ZXL5LCFBhKOYLJYCITCdS7cHQOBINCYXD4IgkAkYFEwdGYkDAbF6b54prpImymCkgbk07nKWDal5ApFJS3KAPJ4vIzvT7fDmgo0KdC8mEC+CcfgaEJmPZWMB4fhOgAWbLCnQ93R6dgcaopYy1U08TMWfFZqzCf02bvgIODGe6XtQPsZJAWKkDUCFGHhwvSdCwlFm-pE4kjVN23Tj8AA9G2EythKDs96yzgML7vgAVOvCQPukP7XrhpzqthnSUTGMzQ3G4DPV7mr4-ZOA2ImdNdaxZ6w5vMwMZF0LwEsI8uIlpVmuD4cwMdshsa5fa5vWK9gHbTsd2+UEM1BVAoG0EBuBOWoEAAeUoGARijID3RPKwqm+Go6nxRViRgINpysA45wyck0IuVdZgLeNljZX4Dyyf5-2nDt4B8Lx4G0HAeW44CsJDcj+nnQYfxoq5pg0dcMEeTdTTeD5d2Y-5WJ2YSIODDAFBOJDemyWBoN4W8jKvGD9G4BgCJaJV2m+JQAHIDicq1g043T9PgRDDOM7RTPgJQxMoiTF01FdpJuO55JNbcVO+NTNhUXtrC5SErn7VgiPlEV7P0djsuVLxyMbaMnXo-c4y8DAcAAVROfSYDRI17CCIJSmAmwAGsoAUYSdGK0rJPKwD90AmqcAAMSwNgpQ0AAmdrOs4nBev68xhJtO1oX5OFnQwV0SNIi8y3zeYQBvO9S0fEUXz6IiG2orUOuEltKs40DiIAfgAQl+v6tNSqxtrAe09vwA6FqOqcTqy87C2LG7SxFMUJSxQaHJVKjKRewr3ouyaGqalrCldfHz3hwCrvvEhbuRVEMQxx6FyXJs3oAsZJpmubpSWwrtOSSDoNg+C6gAcSob4sDB2HsOoXCEPgEUJBgfxjunZ7gCMBGGMTdlRA5qwRu1oK5IUrczQSmAUszYScJgPCEFswkiI1kTemYaROFQHh4G6kAFBwRBlfSVX-E0ELnFo7i-FeFW1e4JQmBUJKYg0oEgc24N0p5U6iqx3LCOVQrMf0ErZzKyLW3WarauJ75SbajqurWvqBqIiuwzCtnRrGcaudqnn5qWlvVvW4G724W0wd22FIdgw63SNzLczOuMaeRhE7voB7lSe3GJle4MCYWLrGJEeAAB9lItYjZJALHxAASXgYRkFg7hvvENxkDLVBBxvzgFADAQQs5bWnjtPk88nSL2hsvE+lM15BQ3kjB8KMGbiiZvNMuJIcboT-CvOu9VGqN1auTFe+clDUzQXTDBLQ0bYOlLg7GPcIqEMQVYCaQ9Zoj2Pt0bSgtzBQRgnBJWdVUACkQogEcyAzgIDlvAB2TtQ4tHDrwRR3QtY6zjCybsKhDacOkL3U2BoYoWyUl9W2AjhJeQMnYdRk4gosCEP7QOwdVHUHUSoHWUd4AuCijMWOicjAJ38MnVO+5-hFiSEoAOQcQ5hO4CoQqbYABUTo9L2JAI428K9gpkirpca4MxdFdiYlE5K194D5L8Ww38tFzZxStnfNOwAizCTSW2e2CtHZKxdq0ZU7tujkWCf4IwvkHGJwzsAAWk9c4IHziwoudkiKl07qVLWlwa4RGIQ3Zq5DlpdW+HkGAv0O5DUrls8QdELp6IqbXeiRNSEHLJu1VuE9gwsK7vYepUkxrrG4dNXhfMjmcROfxc5XyNmVxNpcDQgEWmqQHsAbmILFpgs7G3DaECZ7gxgQdGGlD4aoNvLTMs9DqD3RlE-fBTZjkwFOf9X6pEal22zt0BZ+LHSUowMUb2sggoXzEEE3wIS7yKDaQY-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)