# how do I get the type of a methods arguments in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to get the type of arguments of a method like I get it from a function.
This does not work:

```
function func(a: number, b: string): string {
  return b;
}

type ftype = Parameters<typeof func>;

class Klasse {
  method(a: number, b: string): string {
    return b;
  }
}

// this does not work
type mtype = Parameters<typeof klasse.method>;
```

And no, I don't want to transform method to a static method, it's just a simplified example.

---Edit---

The solution works, but not for overloads:

```
class Klasse {
  method(a: string, b: number): void;
  method(a: number, b: string): void;
  method(a: number | string, b: number | string): string {
    return 'x';
  }
}

// this does not work
// type mtype = Parameters<typeof klasse.method>;
type mtype = Parameters<Klasse["method"]>;

const a: mtype = [0, ''];
const b: mtype = ['', 9]; // error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameters generic of overloaded function doesn't contain all options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535995/parameters-generic-of-overloaded-function-doesnt-contain-all-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, you can use the type utility [`Parameters<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to derive a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of a function's parameters.

Because a function is a **value** in your program (not a type), deriving the **type** of the function requires using the [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html), as shown below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAKAhgLkWEBbAIwFMAnAGkQOwGcoSYwBzAShroccQG8AoRREkSggSSAgG4eAXx48oATwAORRADEAjIgC8iAAroS6PENLUAPCggA+cYgD0AKkQBREiTgk+-bz99+AfoH+PADkliECRMCmiFBwiOiIAG7oADYgRBQEIFCIMNSURByIINREACYJBYkKyogAFqREAHSIACIwlfJwIIjG6EghtURwwMjgECEA-KgATADsACwAnMyIDnayw2qz2noGRiYk5sOj45A29naIcADWXlcAelM8QA)

```ts
function func(a: number, b: string): string {
  return b;
}

type F1 = Parameters<func>; /* Error
                     ~~~~
'func' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof func'?(2749) */

type F2 = Parameters<typeof func>; // ok
   //^? type F2 = [a: number, b: string]
```

In JavaScript, [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are just special functions that we can write using language [syntax sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Deriving the type of a class works the same way as with other functions: `typeof Klasse`.

In order to refer to the type of an **instance** of the class, you can simply use the name of the class: TypeScript automatically creates a type name in scope that represents this when the class is in scope of your code: `Klasse`.

> TypeScript also provides another utility type for doing this: [`InstanceType<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype)

Here's some code to demonstrate and juxtapose what I described above:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDS5QKbQN4ChrQLaIC4AsB7AEwAowAuaAOwFcsAjRAJwBpoGqJdmBLagOYBKLj34DUGTNGZ5azahwDcUgL5p1aXAE8ADsniQIiWIm0wAvNADWZwgDNoO-Q7gJjK6QHovAPQD8aFp6Bu6IAJLU3GDUwCZmljZ2joZInpg+AUHOoUYRUbgxcabmAEzQVrbarpHRsYgAKiEAPDmuqcYAfOnQmYHB+tAAsnhExAAKYMxgWImT0zi4LBDNHYgA2gDki2ObALrdUr1+-TnDoyTzMxDlVleLy821hfVN+q0h7WGdWzsk+4dvCc0EA)

```ts
class Klasse {
  method(a: number, b: string): string {
    return b;
  }
}

type KlasseKeys = keyof typeof Klasse;
   //^? type KlasseKeys = "prototype"

type KlasseInstanceKeys = keyof Klasse;
   //^? type KlasseInstanceKeys = "method"

type KlasseInstanceKeys2 = keyof InstanceType<typeof Klasse>;
   //^? type KlasseInstanceKeys2 = "method"

type MethodParams = Parameters<Klasse['method']>;
   //^? type MethodParams = [a: number, b: string]

type MethodParams2 = Parameters<InstanceType<typeof Klasse>['method']>;
   //^? type MethodParams2 = [a: number, b: string]
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `Klasse` is the type of an instance of `Klasse`.

```
type mtype = Parameters<Klasse["method"]>;
```