# Remove a constructor signature (or a call signature) from a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

### The problem

Having a generic type `T` that has a constructor signature (eg. this type: `{ new(): any }`), return a type `U` that is the same as `T` except it lacks the constructor signature. Adding the constructor signature back to `U` should result in the two types being identical.

### Why do I need this

Let's say I'm writing a function that takes a class and changes its *constructor signature* to something different. This is often the case with proxies, for example this proxy removes the last argument from the constructor call and logs it:

```js
function trapClass(cl) {
    return new Proxy(cl, {
        construct: (target, args) => {
            console.log( args.pop() )
            return new target(...args)
        }
    })
}

class Foo { constructor(...args){ console.log(args) } }
const Bar = trapClass(Foo)
new Foo(1, 2, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
new Bar(1, 2, 3) // 3, [1, 2]
```

How do I type this? The function `trapClass<T>(cl: T)` should be a generic function that takes `T` with a constructor signature and returns `T` with different constructor signature. When I try to intersect `T` with the new signature, like this: `T & { new(a, b, c): any }`, then the new singature doesn't replace the old one, instead it merges with it into an overloaded call.

If I knew how to remove the constructor singature from `T`, the problem would be trivial.

### Call signature

While I don't need to omit a *call signature* from `T`, the problems of removing the constructor signature and the call signature are really similar. I expect that the solutions to these two problems will only differ in a `new` keyword and having `Parameters` instead of `ConstructorParameters`. So I thought the answer could maybe mention both of these problems. However, if the solutions aren't so similar, don't bother with call signatures, I'll make a separate question :)

Comment: Should the desired solution work for _any_ class or just for `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type `T` doesn't include any index signature, then removing constructor and call signatures is as easy as:

```js
type U = Pick<T, keyof T>
```

for some reason that I don't fully understand, [this breaks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200620#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyMmAFAJQBcyALAEwHHKU0gCuAtgEbRPEgIAd1bIAzmCigA5vyJQIcACboQAGwCeybnCg1ac5AG0A1hA00JUkNIC6bLryjIAPmnYgEYYKoIBfAgIwDQAHFFIsAF4cYwBpZFBkMw10GDRMe3T0I1jbZAD8YLDtXWRogAVgBBMAHgx0ABok81SsgD4CIA) with index signatures. My guess is that `Pick` doesn't preserve the union-type in its second argument. A completely fool-proof way to do this is:

```js
type U = { [K in keyof T]: keyof T }
```

Now, this removes *both* a call signature and a constructor signature. If we wanted to remove only one of those, we could add the other back. So these are the final types:

```js
type OmitCallSignature<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } &
    (T extends new (...args: infer R) => infer S ? new (...args: R) => S : unknown)

type OmitConstructorSignature<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } &
    (T extends (...args: infer R) => infer S ? (...args: R) => S : unknown)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AYQIYBt0GUEHMB2qwArgE4QA8AKgHxQC8AsAFBRtQDeUA2gNJQJ8UANYQQAewBmUKgF0AXDL6yoAXygAyFuygAKKlAgAPYBHwATAM5R8EAO56AdM9SlclxYMkRSUAEoAlAx0Xj5QWFAA-Db2Ti5uHv5B9HQRisT4wvjidvgBLCygkLCIKOL4lsCkxADGwOKkOAREZJS0DNrsXHwCQqIS0nKKVMpqmp1s+oYmZlZxjq7unvjevoHBvavhUfOLiesp2+mZ2bn5zCyCpqSSqDXQAGLi4pwTeqiKAIwBivjEcAAjHxvWx2XQ-KCVUiCXBvSTPcGKAAsACY3uRUOZyugQFAAa5kW9uP1FFCYQobP8gb4AD5QB4ZOoIcosVQFZhFaDwl70EpINCYJqEEjkChPcQ0QrgaD43y8+D88pQ2r1Rp4YWtMXPGhAA)

.

What? You say that these types [mess up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=37&pln=12&pc=18#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AYQIYBt0GUEHMB2qwArgE4QA8AKgHxQC8AsAFBRtQDeUA2gNJQJ8UANYQQAewBmUKgF0AXDL6yoAXygAyFuygAKKlAgAPYBHwATAM5R8EAO56AdM9SlclxYMkRSUAEoAlAx0Xj5QWFAA-Db2Ti5uHv5B9HQRisT4wvjidvgBLCygkLCIKOL4lsCkxADGwOKkOAREZJS0DNrsXHwCQqIS0nKKVMpqmp1s+oYmZlZxjq7unvjevoHBvavhUfOLiesp2+mZ2bn5zCyCpqSSqDXQAGLi4pwTeqiKAIwBivjEcAAjHxvXQfKAAJh+Nn+QNIb1sdl0UMqpEEuBYqgKzCK0EkzwYJSQaEwTUIJHIFCe4hohXA0ABrgJ8CJ5RRtXqjTwZNalOeNCAA) with overloaded call signatures? Oh yes, they really do mess up with overloaded call signatures. What a shame. To be honest, I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function) concerning the overloaded call signatures.

Answer (score 1):

**TypeScript 3.x**

You can try this:

```
type Constructor<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function trapClass<T extends Constructor>(cl: T): Pick<T, keyof T> & { new (a: number, b: number): T } {
  return new Proxy(cl, {
      construct: (target, args) => {
          console.log( args.pop() )
          return new target(...args)
      }
  })
}

class Foo { constructor(...args: any[]){ console.log(args) } }
const Bar = trapClass(Foo);

new Foo(1, 2, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
new Bar(1, 2, 3) // 3, [1, 2]
```

This will work for `Foo`. If you want `trapClass` to work with *any* class, the solution would be more complicated — you'd have to account for classes that don't accept any arguments, and for classes in which the number of arguments for the constructor is variadic.

Notice the `Pick<T, keyof T>` part. When `T` is a constructor, the resulting type will be an object containing the static properties of that constructor. For a constructor `Foo`, it will be `{ prototype: Foo }`. If you add a static property (or method) to `Foo`, it will appear in that object as well. Effectively, it will remove the construct signature from `Foo`.

```
class Foo {
    constructor(...args: [number, number, number]) {
        console.log(args)
    }

    static defaults = {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
};

const Bar = trapClass(Foo);

Bar.defaults.foo; // string
```

Side note: it's exactly the same as using the common `Overwrite` helper.

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;

function trapClass<T extends Constructor>(cl: T): Overwrite<T, { new (...args: [number, number]): T }> {
  return new Proxy(cl, {
      construct: (target, args) => {
          console.log( args.pop() )
          return new target(...args)
      }
  })
}
```

**TypeScript 4**

TypeScript 4 includes support for [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094). This allows you to dynamically remove the last argument from the original constructor type.

```
type DropLast<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly [...infer U, any] ? U : [...T];

type Constructor<T extends readonly unknown[], U> = new (...args: T) => U;

function trapClass<T extends Constructor<any, any>>(cl: T): Constructor<DropLast<ConstructorParameters<T>>, T> {
  return new Proxy(cl, {
      construct: (target, args) => {
          console.log( args.pop() )
          return new target(...args)
      }
  })
}

class Foo {
    constructor(...args: [number, number, number]) {
        console.log(args)
    }
}
const Bar = trapClass(Foo);

new Foo(1, 2, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
new Bar(1, 2, 3) // Compile-time error (expected 2 args)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=4.0.0-pr-39094-7&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=67#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgezAGQIYGdgB4AqUIAewEAdgCbpRwSpkIkA2IUAriQNYkIDuJA2gF0AfFAC8UPIWLlK1WvSZQ+AOlUBLEgDMIcKAFUANFFQkQAqAH59UAFxLVynAIDcAKFehIUAML1McFgBjYAQ4XHwiUgoqGjpGZjZOHn4BIz0RcRIIbigACgdUOABzdDscAEoxET03V002YLV6KGA4VDBvBgx0cKkoyl8SfyCQsJMQI3GhIVzAhjLyu0Hh4NCseCQ0TCxl1pHQgAVC1ABbCGI4Hpxpo2uoAG9XKBjgFjgSKCycg8QCEFmGEZHs8QVBAn49sE7LlgIUiudJsV0JVRCJgaCMeChggGBBlAwEEVcsYkcowEhcpVyk8MaDqK93p9si04ed8qo4ciaaCAL40nnUvmuObdKAAMQQCAe3LBEICqzg7OUnLsfBILBOACMdEZ1VqdZ8Ndq4AJKujaVj0Di8QSiZzqbzXHzLcAoAAhQpiFptDpddDoXIShDlWpfcWS3IARiMACYjABmSoAeiTSmjUDjUHjAlcYY9ivTmcTUBTPgQJzAalxAFpgGozvg4IhdLlCJBghAyBmSSVykA)

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what I need! Would you, please, explain how this works? Does `Pick<T, keyof T>` make a type that is exactly `T` but without call and constructor signatures? The gist of the question is „how to remove constructor signature“, so if this is true, the real answer is as simple as `type U<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>`! ️

Comment: That's right. It does remove the construct signature. However, it feels more idiomatic to use the `Constructor<T, U>` approach from the second method instead.

Comment: Might be more idiomatic, but doesn't answer the question! :D Anyway, thanks! I didn't expect the solution would be this easy!