# TypeScript: override a method return type that has overloads

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I'm working on a opensource library that makes Proxies of Rx Observables.

*(I'll use `Box<A>` instead of `Observable<A>` for simplicity)*

It takes in a `Box<A>` and returns a type `{ [P in keyof A]: Box<A[P]> }`.

With one nuance: all methods on this new type should also return a `Box` of that method result, while keeping it's params types. So:

```
Box<{ m(a:string):any }>
// becomes
{ m(a:string):Box<any> }
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to proxy `A` that has overloaded methods on it — I'm only redefining **one single method definition**, not the whole overload group.

Simplified issue:

```
type Proxy<O> = { [P in keyof O]: Wrap<O[P]> }

type Wrap<O> = O extends (...a: infer P) => infer R
  ? (...args: P) => Proxy<R>
  : Proxy<O>

class A {
  m(a: number): any;
  m(a: string): any;
  m(...a:any[]) {}
}

let p = {} as Proxy<A>;
// p.m resolves to a single override
// m(a: string): void;
p.m('1') // > returns Proxy<any>
p.m(1)   // > Error: 1 is not string
```

[Try this snippet in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewB4gDwHkB8UC8UDeUA2jFAJYB2UA1hCAgGZToC6AXFAOpwCGYGJFtgC+AKFGhIXXvyy5mUCEmAQKAEwDOUABQA6fTw6UGEOLACUubMdNQASqKhQA-Dv26ecAOYaOMSzjY8MhodpiOUH6IKBjhogDGADY8GloAggQRALbahlAUAK5ZAEam5hwAbghkagDc2bkcGsBwlF7lUFU19U457oY8FCBELJb4YmKiiRDAUGDy41ApsNFoaZj1YLo5AIzmogD0B1AAelAAonCIcIfHZLNwEBoIiRXQwAhLUBpt01AIbyuNQg4iAA)

Is it even possible?

Please, help me with this typing. Thanks!

**Notes:**

Everything already works fine without typings!

You can check out the library here: [rxjs-proxify](https://github.com/kosich/rxjs-proxify#readme) (types defined in `src/proxify.ts`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with mapping overloaded functions. If you just use `O extends (...a: infer P) => infer R` you will actually always get the last overload. There is no way to get the arguments for an arbitrary number of overloads, but you can create a conditional type to get the overloaded arguments for up to a certain number of overloads using the technique outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function/52761156#52761156)

```
type Proxy<O> = { [P in keyof O]: OverloadedWrap<O[P]> }

type OverloadedWrap<T> =
    T extends
        { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; (...args: infer A3): infer R3; (...args: infer A4): infer R4 } ? 
        { (...args: A1): Proxy<R1>; (...args: A2): Proxy<R2>; (...args: A3): Proxy<R3>; (...args: A4): Proxy<R4>; }:
    T extends
        { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; (...args: infer A3): infer R3; } ? 
        { (...args: A1): Proxy<R1>; (...args: A2): Proxy<R2>; (...args: A3): Proxy<R3>; }:
    T extends
        { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2; } ? 
        { (...args: A1): Proxy<R1>; (...args: A2): Proxy<R2>; }:
    T extends
        { (...args: infer A1): infer R1; } ? 
        { (...args: A1): Proxy<R1>; }:
    Proxy<T>

type Wrap<O> = O extends (...a: infer P) => infer R
    ? (...args: P) => Proxy<R>
    : Proxy<O>

class A {
    m(a: boolean): any;
    m(a: number): any;
    m(a: string): any;
    m(...a: any[]) { }
}

let p = {} as Proxy<A>;
p.m('1') // > returns Proxy<any>
p.m(1)   // > returns Proxy<any>
p.m
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIAUBOB7AHuAPAeQHywLywDesA2vLAJYB2sA1tOMgGaxYC6AXGwG7SIAbZAEMAJtFEB1RMMjZy7PAF8QEGL35CxE6bIwAVPPmCxTsfbGipQ0aqIDOJs85IAKAHSfhiAOb3uNMz8sACCAIwAlAHUQYiwAEphANywHl6+-lQxwSEATFFZsQm5KWnu3n7RRSEAzAWBwfE1pZ7lGVU5ACz12XHxnbBKsAD8sE7Opm6tFZnhBUhomIk4LemVofncC+gY8bkrqdPtoXVbKDtNB2Uz3CHdZ4u7nQdKnOPmlta2Du8uh2uZBpxOYdPrJf5tdZAjY9Ip7VaQwG9E6wxrNQYjMYTMxTAG3SIPC5hK5HdZ5ebnJb7BE3FGEpY1F5vZwWKw2OyObGTCG06EgwqNcHXY58zYCvolDGjX44nnHfnbJbEmnysWK3bUwbMsysr4cmXc4VQ5H86GJFJDaVc4hyskEhCU3bKrXvdWGVRQOC6OS4AhsT7shw80EICIEPBm96jI2ZeBh-B4dXxHDvenYFPAADGAmE9nsoWI7wAtq5hNwAEbIZACaDCagFOvgJLF0vcagAVyL5f4DeoTZbZdg9lAiBoPl7-ecJem3EbpHYYZIKhUwBroFgkD9RCGuYdjxCK2AkHcJYA5GFT2GAPRX2B4RDQUDtxDUfPqxsp48lyJmG932APk+L5vo6H5HieQA)

Comment: Ah! Works like a charm! Thanks!

Though I'm getting some weird behavior from overloaded methods on `Box` now: they have n overloads, though default to `B.method(a: any)` rather than `B.method(a: number)`. Will try to figure that out.

Again, big thanks, Titian 

Comment: Good point, thanks! I see that `strictFunctionTypes` in tsconfig also affects how types are inferred for proxied funcs. With `strictFunctionTypes: true` behaves well, but without it -- it breaks. Not sure how that'll affect library end-users. I might wait for TS 5 Ty!