# Why does an intersection change when the types are reordered?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question. I'm teaching myself TypeScript and according to my tutorial the order of the types in an intersection shouldn't matter, e.g. `A & B` and `B & A` should be the same type.

But I stumbled upon this edge case where the order of the types does matter, although I don't understand why.

```
abstract class Test
{
    constructor(a: string, b: boolean)
    { }
}

type A = typeof Test;
type B = new (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;

type AB = ConstructorParameters<A & B>; // unknown[]
type BA = ConstructorParameters<B & A>; // [a: string, b: boolean]
```

How does the order affect the resulting type in this particular case?

Are there any more edge cases I should be aware of?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

> When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the last signature (which, presumably, is the most permissive catch-all case). It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types.

More explanation you can find [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27027#issuecomment-420305933)

When you made intersection of two functions - it is mean you made an overloading.

See next example:

```js
type A = (a: number) => number
type B = (b: string) => string
type C = (c: any) => any
declare var foo: A & B & C

foo(2) // number
foo('2') // string
foo({}) // any
```

Above code is equal to:

```js
    function bar(a: string): string;
    function bar(a: number): number;
    function bar(a: any): any;
    function bar(a: number | string | any) {
        return null as any

    }
    bar(2); // number
    bar('2') // string
    bar({}) // any
```

Please keep in mind, that I put less specific `a:any` at the end. And it works as expected.

But, what if I put it at the beginning:

```js
    function bar(a: any): any;
    function bar(a: string): string;
    function bar(a: number): number;
    function bar(a: number | string | any) {
        return null as any

    }
    bar(2); // any
    bar('2') // any
    bar({}) // any
}
```

All ReturnTypes are `any`. Because less specific overloading is at the beginning.

Same here:

```js
type A = (a: number) => number
type B = (b: string) => string
type C = (c: any) => any
declare var foo: C & B & A

foo(2) // any
foo('2') // any
foo({}) // any
```

**UPDATE**

Let's dig into `ConstructorParameters`. What does it mean?

```js
// this is what ConstructorParameters doing under the hood
type Check = A extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : never // number
type Check2 = (A & B) extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : never // string
type Check3 = (A & B & C) extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : never // any
```

It just takes the last intersected item and infers it's parameters.

So if I put `A` as a last item, it will infer only `A` params:

```js
    type Check4 = (C & B & A) extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : never // number
```

So if you are doing intersection of functions - you should treat is as overloading.

Edge case: if you have function types with generics - intersection it might not work. I don't know/understand why.

Comment: Relative SO questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450360/bug-in-typescript-generics-or-just-me-being-stupid & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function