# How to get first parameter types of overloaded methods in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```js
interface App {
  on(event: 'child-process-gone', handler: () => void): void;
  on(event: 'render-process-gone', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
}

const app: App = {
  on(event: string, handler: Function) {console.log(event, handler)}
};

type A = Parameters<typeof app.on>[0]; // A = "render-process-gone"

// type EventType = How<typeof app.on> // EventType = "child-process-gone" | "render-process-gone"
```

How to get all the types of first parameter `event`?

FYI:

[Parameter type interface for overloaded functions as union type #32164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164)

An not-perfect solution:

```js
interface App {
  on(event: 'render-process-1', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
  on(event: 'render-process-2', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
  on(event: 'render-process-3', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
  on(event: 'render-process-4', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
  on(event: 'render-process-5', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
  on(event: 'render-process-6', handler: (e: Event) => void): void;
}

const app: App = {
  on(event: string, handler: Function) {console.log(event, handler)}
};

type IntersectionOfFunctionsToTuple<F> =
    F extends {
        (event: infer A, ...rest: any[]): void;
        (event: infer B, ...rest: any[]): void;
        (event: infer C, ...rest: any[]): void;
    } ? [A, B, C] :
    F extends {
        (event: infer A, ...rest: any[]): void;
        (event: infer B, ...rest: any[]): void;
    } ? [A, B] :
    F extends {
        (eventa: infer A, ...rest: any[]): void
    } ? [A] :
    never;

type EventTypes = IntersectionOfFunctionsToTuple<typeof app.on>
// EventTypes = ["render-process-4", "render-process-5","render-process-6"]
```

Comment: Do you have full control over `App` interface with overloadings? If yes, you can make overloading mapping. Here you can find an example https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe#first_approach . Also, this is default behaviour of TS. Compiler will always take last overloading signature. To make it work in a way you want, I believe you should  make other structure of your types.

Comment: I believe this question is very similar to your. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function    I think your approach is only one way to do it

Comment: @captain-yossarian no. that `App` is `electron.App`

Comment: I'd willing to bet that you have seen already this comment https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164#issuecomment-764660652

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes. But in my case, the method has more than 36 overloads which make writing the `type Overloads` unpractical