# Given an overloaded function and parameter types, find the return type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52761156/599184), `ReturnType<>` doesn't work with overloaded functions in general. However, would it be possible to select a particular version of the overloaded function and get its return type?

The only way I can think of is to have code invoking the overloaded function.

```
function fn(arg: string): string;

function fn(arg: number): number;

function fn(arg: string | number): string | number {
    return arg;
}

const temp1 = () => fn('string');
type Type1 = ReturnType<typeof temp1>; // string

const temp2 = () => fn(123);
type Type2 = ReturnType<typeof temp2>; // number
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=39&pln=10&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAhgJwOYC5EDOUmMY2AlPkSWQNwBQ9oksCyaWeiYIAtgEYBTTJW58hmBk3DR4SFBhxVipbIgA%20YgcNHVVGrRMQBveonOJMgqCExJODAL6N6EBEURRBvAA4BGRABeRFRyIIA%20dlQAcj0yaPIGKABPH0FEABVUwQDggCVrWzAstIAeFLS4YE9vf3CpNzAPL18AJiCQsMDIhT9WgGZE%20gr0ksF2-MK7MfLsqpq2%20vogA)

Is there a cleaner way where I don't have to pass in the arguments (just the argument type)?

Comment: I dont think so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799234/typescript-pick-only-specific-method-from-overload-to-be-passed-to-parameterst/68799734#68799734 . I can't find the thread, but TS team has a strong point that it would be unsafe behavior

Comment: You can find the link to the thread in my answer which I already provided you with

Answer (score 0):

By combining the type to get the arguments and the type to get the return type, we can create a type that gets the overloads:

```js
type _Overloads<T> = 
    T extends { (...args: infer A1) : infer R1; (...args: infer A2) : infer R2; (...args: infer A3) : infer R3; (...args: infer A4) : infer R4 } ? [[A1, R1], [A2, R2], [A3, R3], [A4, R4]] :
    T extends { (...args: infer A1) : infer R1; (...args: infer A2) : infer R2; (...args: infer A3) : infer R3 } ? [[A1, R1], [A2, R2], [A3, R3]] :
    T extends { (...args: infer A1) : infer R1; (...args: infer A2) : infer R2 } ? [[A1, R1], [A2, R2]] :
    T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? [[A, R]] : any;
```

(Note that this only works for up to four overloads,  but you can extend it to work for more.)

Then, given an array of overloads, we can get the return type based on the arguments type:

```js
type _OverloadsReturnType<O extends [unknown, unknown][], A> = O extends [[A, infer R], ...unknown[]] ? R :
    O extends [unknown, ...infer S extends [unknown, unknown][]] ? _OverloadsReturnType<S, A> : any;
```

Finally, we create a type that combines the two:

```js
type OverloadsReturnType<T, A> = _OverloadsReturnType<_Overloads<T>, A>;
```

Use it like this:

```js
type ret1 = OverloadsReturnType<typeof fn, [string]>;
//   ^?

type ret2 = OverloadsReturnType<typeof fn, [number]>;
//   ^?
```

(Note that ^? reveals types in the TypeScript Playground.)

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=8&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA+g8gNwgJwDYHsCGATAzgHgBUA+KAXigFgAoKOqQqCAD2AgDs8oBvKACgB0QzMgDmuAFxQAluwBmKKAEEAjAEooU2QuRQASioDc-IQJHit8xUoBMGyzv03jg4WMkyrupQGZ7nxz0fF1NzD21rABZ-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-PK540LoyFzjNxYnLiWjsagT+AKnIUHjbNqWfFNg1jdA5DHIoO0PUR8mIcsAHpEPoAA9FJPxZb9aQBeUs2LJNA1TcDIObIopwvZB4KQlC6HQoA) that demonstrates this.