# Typescript type definition for providing styles to the MUI styled utility

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components, typescript-generics

I'm creating a bunch of styled components ins MUI v5 that have some extra props defined on them.

```
const SomeContainer = styled(Box, {
    name: "SomeContainer",
    slot: "Root"
})<BoxProps & { whatever: string }>(({ theme, someComponentProp }) => ({
    // styles    
}));
```

I would now like to separate the function that returns the styles object into a separate theme file so that I would have `SomeContainer.tsx` and `SomeContainer.styles.ts` files pair

### Problem - defining the type

The content of the styles file would export the styles:

```
export const SomeComponentStyles: ??? = ({ theme, someComponentProp }) => ({
    // styles    
});
```

MUI's Typescript type definitions are very convoluted, and I can't seem to correctly define the type of my export (the `???` part). Sure you can always set configuration to be less strict so you can get away with `any` or not even providing the type, but that won't help with vscode intellisense to improve developer's experience writing these styles.

> **The problem is not, that the code would not compile, but to actually define this type to have a much better dev environment (i.e. vscode) experience when writing these files for various different components?** The IDE would provide correct code hints for function parameter objects as well as for the styles themselves within the resulting object.

### What I tried

`styled` itself is a `function` that returns a `function` that takes an arbitrary number of parameters (objects with style definitions or functions that return such objects - my case). My exported `function` is one of those parameters.

It seems this should be the correct type, but it's not.

```
type StyleDefinition = Parameters<ReturnType<typeof styled>>[0];
```

There's also the additional problem that I'm having with generic function definition where I provide the type as `<BoxProps & { whatever: string }>` which means that my extra props should propagate to the function parameters.

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-smoke-5fo8ff?file=/demo.tsx) to play around.

Comment: pls [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @caTS: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-smoke-5fo8ff?file=/demo.tsx Not sure why would you need this as this is design/compile-time issue I'm having, not a run-time one... But will the provided link do?

Comment: We can't reproduce *any* problems, whether it be run-time or compile-time, without a MRE.

Comment: @caTS. It's not about having a problem or that it wouldn't compile. You can always tweak configuration to be less or more strict to satisfy these... **It's about defining the proper type**, so that intellisense in vscode (or other tools) would be able to provide correct hints.

Comment: @caTS I've edited my question so that it's clear it's not about some compile issue (which I never said it was and you implied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually almost there, but the culprit is the function overload of `styled(Component, options)<AdditionalProps>()`, which makes manipulating its type awkward.

TL; DR:

```
// Use argument at index 1 (instead of 0)
Parameters<ReturnType<typeof styled>>[1];
```

---

When directly executing the `styled(Component)()` function, TypeScript is able to infer the correct function overload to be used.

In your case, you are using the [2nd](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.14/packages/mui-styled-engine/src/index.d.ts#L114-L121) / 4:

```
<AdditionalProps extends {}>(
  ...styles: Array<
    Interpolation<ComponentProps & SpecificComponentProps & AdditionalProps & { theme: T }>
  >
): StyledComponent<ComponentProps & AdditionalProps, SpecificComponentProps, JSXProps>;
```

But when trying to define the argument separately, trying to extract its type with TypeScript [`Parameters` built-in utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), TS uses only *the last function overload*, as described in [Typescript pick only specific method from overload (to be passed to Parameters<T>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799234/typescript-pick-only-specific-method-from-overload-to-be-passed-to-parameterst)

Therefore we get overload [4/4](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.14/packages/mui-styled-engine/src/index.d.ts#L128-L136):

```
<AdditionalProps extends {}>(
  template: TemplateStringsArray,
  ...styles: Array<
    Interpolation<ComponentProps & SpecificComponentProps & AdditionalProps & { theme: T }>
  >
): StyledComponent<ComponentProps & AdditionalProps, SpecificComponentProps, JSXProps>;
```

Hence when trying to get the 1st parameter (at index 0, the one used when we directly execute the function), we get `TemplateStringsArray` type, instead of the one that is inferred when calling the function.

Fortunately, we see that @mui team provided a reasonable API, where the rest parameter is actually the same as in a previous overload: therefore we can simply get the next one, instead of the 1st (i.e. skip index 0):

```
// Use argument at index 1 (instead of 0)
Parameters<ReturnType<typeof styled>>[1];
```

---

> There's also the additional problem that I'm having with generic function definition where I provide the type as `<BoxProps & { whatever: string }>` which means that my extra props should propagate to the function parameters.

We can simply define the function with its actual Component and AdditionalProps ahead, then use its type:

```
const createStyledBox = styled(Box, {
    name: "SomeContainer",
    slot: "Root"
})<BoxProps & { whatever: string }>;

type BoxStyles = Parameters<typeof createStyledBox>[1];

const boxStyles: BoxStyles = ({ theme, whatever }) => ({
  // styles
  padding: theme.spacing(1.5),
  //       ^? Theme
  backgroundColor: whatever === "val" ? "white" : "black",
  //               ^? string
});

const SomeContainer2 = createStyledBox(boxStyles);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZxgTwDYFMAmcC+cAZlBCHAEQACIArsAPTJqpYgUDcAUKJLInABCEAB4AaIaIAKpMMgLFS5anUYgAhjCxRg6jJy6GAxhAB2qOAGUyWAMJmY64Ke1wAvCnTYcACmHjELjhguAYGAD0AfiCQ03UQLAAuSmsE+1NHZ20KMRjg5AwIGGSKACUIIooufABKAB5-GQg5OAAyAQB3AAtNLAA3bWTUHVMAcwIAPh8fJBgutiwJbt6BqAIa9wm4GbzQhk9MLGRdsHUcHGdR5IADABIEOYWAOmRTo0ufAEYngFYawnujwSLzeHwATP9rrkQnsYXC4FFdgAjdRGADWo1ItFMOHshSgyWWWlW7jcHgofT0FDgkUoAGIiOdqSVusAtDldmF4dzgojajVuFx0GAsFYvFgACJYIjONnAMzuOBSdRQeJYLRQZB1Urq2hQUwAFTQIrqwqwECIB28EwmAG1PgBdbhckKIrgmczwIxQLC9SzinD+RWoQ6+fwSBCciLRGFxBIlVJ2BxOFxQDkwgpFErlSrVeqNWTydpIIn9QaeEbjfATQVmyQif2HeQeZWqhIarVmi1wb2+rSN7z+O2O537XnRd1mCxI0QDo7Jfxz5vbWbzBJLHrE1y1TYrqNWo4nM4XMY3QFrrAg1Efb5-AEPC9X95jHwQ-BQ-c8hExkIo9GYiBsVxCB8UJTcyzWMlyUpfQaXpRkcGZShWXZaEQhdL8YT5AVjCneBE3STJUzBRVez9AN-B8GcG3FZABVhAB5NF1DQLggA)

---

If you want to further decouple the style from the styled component creation, you can indeed define a general type (possibly with generics), and let TypeScript check the structural compatibility when you use it with the creator function:

```
import { Interpolation, styled, Theme } from "@mui/system";

type InterpolationWithTheme<Props extends {}> = Interpolation<Props & { theme: Theme }>

const whateverStyles: InterpolationWithTheme<{ whatever: string }> = ({ theme, whatever }) => ({
    // styles
    padding: `${theme.spacing(1.5)} ${theme.spacing(2)}`,
    //          ^? Theme
    backgroundColor: whatever === "val" ? "#fdd" : "white",
    //               ^? string
});

const SomeContainer3 = styled(Box, {
    name: "SomeContainer",
    slot: "Root"
})<BoxProps & { whatever: string }>(whateverStyles); // Okay
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=55&ssc=61&pln=41&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQHYwKZUgGwIYzASoA0cAzjAJ44YAmZAKgBYYgZwC+cAZlBCDgAiAAIgArsAD05KpTZCA3AChQkWIjgAhCAA8yO3QAV+Ycl179BoidJAEswPDiXK3AY2KU4AZQEYAYWIYPGBULDgAXgpqWjoACkMyBGU4NLgpKQA9AH5U9NQ8dgAuYT92IPRQ8KghEny08hwIGFKhACUIFqFlTgBKAB5DEwgzOAAyTQB3ZgcANyxSyigwgHMuAD54+KQYVnYyGfmI-qiNuB2GjKkYmgxyK7A8Ojo10oADABIEPbYMADpyE93Gt4gBGf4AVj63G+v3YgOBoIATDD3vV0tdMdi4LkrgAjPDuADWq344lQdCCzSgpSOmAWUCikWiQjmziEcBywgAxDwXpy2jNgJg6ldMjjJWk8f0+iplNQwBwfLEMAARDA8MIioioKJwIx4KBFDCYKDkAbtU3iKCoRhUJUDRUYCA8W5xDYbADaYIAuioJek8cpPKhvO4oBgHCq7nRDPrKLHEnpkuLsnlMYUSmV-JUQmEsGLMU0Wm1Ot1eoNhqZzJMkPSMIyljAVqh1pwNvLndo9DHaOZoobjewzRbna64BGo5g+-RDN6-QGbtK8iGvPB8b3VeRSoZZwOLrt9hhDrMGSc+mdD2n3fdHs9Xm2PnDj4iiaCIdDYT9X0D3234lRTh0RvKVcQzdJCRJMkIApKkIBpOkz0bCIWVZdkXC5Xl+ToQVhGFUUMXSQMwMxGU5Q8ddfFzYJqiwZF9SnaNVTjPR4k3XR9zlLEAHliTwKg3EyYSRNEsTxIk4S3G7NAzVwAhdQAdRFZgWD+AYRjGDBdEwSlzAQDt9VkrB5MIYgNJrCZNHhDBSjU9hNkosN4AbRl91KYzsAQhTiGUvZ7IwAZ62QpsYlbdtzmiHY4Bs09jiZU5InOS5MQlRN+3vF43jgL4fz+N8QQAz8YTgF98r-QrVkAtEiLSEjJTxTEoNJclKWpaAkPi5l0I5LChD5AU4CFZgRQwItiOXUigzyfp5VDbxykCWiCygABmBMWOTfREDTRqChNNpFrzOjalqihmlaYRyxgHp+iGPRNNraYQsWMK1k2eJXKwLjFF4-jBKAA)

Comment: The last part where you just use the `createStyledBox` function to get the type wouldn't work in my case. I mention that I want to separate the styles to some other file, which means that the component would import the style file. Style file therefore can't import the component file because of circular dependency. It also means that every file should define the type, which beats the purpose of the whole *acrobatics* we're doing here...

Comment: And BTW. Your other parts of the answer are brilliant. but for the time being this is what I'm using, because it seems it serves my purpose exactly: `export type ComponentStyles<TProps extends object> = CSSObject | ((input: TProps & { theme: Theme }) => CSSObject);`. Using this I can easily create the styles as `ComponentStyles<BoxProps & { whatever: string}>` and I get correct types for function parameters as well as for style object definition that is consumed by the styled-component *creator* function. I'll consider your solution too, weighing in maintenance simplicity.

Comment: Yes you can further decouple the style from the call, then it is up to you to maintain them in sync (compatibility-wise). I added a general type in the above answer.

Comment: Your answer already deserves the bounty, so I've awarded it already. **But I hope this won't stop you from answering my next question.** Would it be possible to define the `InterpolationWithTheme<>` type by using the reverse type extraction from `styled` so by means of using the likes of `ReturnType`, `Parameters` and such? Because that would make `InterpolationWithTheme<>` type future proof to always correctly match the definition of `styled` even if that gets changed in the future.

Comment: It should be possible, now that TS handles instantiation expression, or with some workarounds. I will try when I get more time.