# Wrapping and narrowing function definition overloaded through intersection

Tags: typescript

I have the following function definition (from an external library):

```
interface Options {
  format?: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
}

declare function foo(options: Options & { format?: 'a' }): string;
declare function foo(options: Options & { format: 'b' }): Uint8Array;
declare function foo(options: Options & { format: 'c' }): Object;
```

I am wrapping `foo` with another function `wrapper`, which takes the same options as `foo`, except that I want to prevent the caller from using `format: 'c'`. This is what I tried:

```
interface WrapperOptions extends Options {
  format?: 'a' | 'b'
}
function wrapper(options: WrapperOptions) {
  return foo(options); <--- error
}
```

I get errors due to `'a' | 'b'` not being assignable to `format: 'c'` (and so on).
This makes sense, so I added a more generic `foo` declaration (following the existing ones):

```
declare foo(options: Options): string | Uint8Array | Object
```

The problem with this for me, is that when calling e.g. `wrapper({ format: 'a' })`, the output type is not narrowed down to `string`, but instead I get `string | Uint8Array | Object`.

My question is: is there a way to "reuse" the existing `foo` definitions while preserving the (narrow) output type inference?

Comment: The problem is that you can't map the multiple `foo` signatures to `wrapper` signatures. This answer might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function

Comment: There's no programmatic way to manipulate all the overloads of a function; it's a TS limitation.  You can *kind of* work around it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7PzGm), which does what you're trying to do but with a lot of complexity that is almost certainly not worth it.  You'd be better off just taking responsibility for type safety on yourself and doing something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrK3om).  Let me know if you want any or all of this written up as an answer.