# How can i extends function's return type and argument

Tags: typescript

here is library's function

```
interface FUNCTION {
  <A, B, C>(a)=>RETURN<A, B>
  <A, B, C>(a, b)=>RETURN<A, B>
  <A, B, C>(a, b, c)=>RETURN<A, B>
  ...
}
```

I want to change RETURN type to contain my optional property y or more and optional argument d or more.
In this moment is there any way to declare augmented function type?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoFEAqBVVA5AHgEEBeOEATwBpkAhMygPgG8BYAKGWQGcB7AWwgAuZESocuYABagA5iNocAvh1XtQkWIhQAxbHkwBJAPJ5kbTsmINqdGzQDCNxsgAUcEWOQAjIbRoIQg4AlCIYOPjENLSMANwSVqTktvTJjs5uHqI0vrShaFi4hF4x8ZbWaXaVTsku7p4BQfnhRVF0cQkVlNH2yDVMmZ7NhZElHeVJ3VUD9dk+fsMRxdHjXF0pGbNEi61jZSrsHBrQ8EjIALIAmi2jvakDEAAekCAAJtwFS20xFlz8FCJuGAoHJlGogA)
i want to change FUNCTION to return MYRETURN without defining all of overloadings of FUNCTION

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wRRa1w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz thanks. i added more information in the post. Does it help to understand problem?

Comment: Please put the example code directly into the question as plain text.  Playground links are good supplements, but they are not sufficient by themselves.

Comment: I think you are asking for a way to programmatically transform an interface so as to modify the return type of every call signature in the interface.  If so, then this won't really be easily possible because the language doesn't make it easy to manipulate overloads; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52760509/2887218) for example.  Furthermore you are looking for manipulating *generic function types*, which is also difficult.  So if I'm right about your question, then I think the answer is pretty much "no, sorry"

Comment: If you want this question to be answered, I'd suggest fixing it up so that your code example clearly shows what your desired output is. Also please try to adhere to coding conventions and standards.  Type names are conventionally written in UpperPascalCase and not ALLCAPS.  Call signatures should not have unused generic type parameters; there's no use in having `C` in the call signature `<A,B,C>(a:A,b:B):Return<A,B>`.  If you aren't trying to ask about coding standards and conventions, then having nonstandard and unconventional code is only a distraction from what you are trying to ask.