# Infer a parameter of an overload function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to `infer` a parameter of an overload function?

For instance:

```js
type MyFunction = {
  (key: "one", params: { first: string }): void;
  (key: "two", params: { second: string }): void;
}

type MyFunctionParams<T extends string> = MyFunction extends (
  key: T,
  params: infer P,
) => void
  ? P
  : never;

// should be `{ first: string }`
type OneParams = MyFunctionParams<"one"> // never
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigG8AoKKACgGsIQAuKAIhwgYBoowBDAJ04FsAzvUJQAZhm4Dg9KdwzIA5lAC+ASnoA3LBgAmAblIVqdRsADuWNhx78hRKAIiocOmcDmKV6qFt0HlxMSgkLAIKOjYyAAKNoIAPAAqUBAAHsAQyDoCDu7yCgB8+KFIaJg4yWkZWRSGxvQJrIZcvIL08qIQ3FBRjar4hb46hgD83Yb0yBAanQbEAPRzDgAWWIgANjpQAEbQAAYi4pLSOR5KyrtB4NAA8pMxLdkEcCUROPe2cUyTDIULUJPTbhAA)

Comment: Why `{ first: string }` and not `{ second: string }`? How would you choose?

Comment: Because `... MyFunction extends (key: T, ...` I guess? Calling a function typed with `MyFunction` with the first param as `"one"` is enough for typescript to know that the second param should be `{ first: string; }`, so I assume typescript should be able to figure the same stuff out when using `extends` in `MyFunctionParams` generic, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If** you control the definition of `MyFunction`, I would follow [caTS's excellent approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209253/157247) of coming at it from another angle. *(It's striking sometimes how if you change your starting point, you can simplify something or even make something possible that wasn't originally possible, often without negative consequences.)*

If you have to use an existing `MyFunction` type, though, then: Two possible solutions for you, a general one and a more pragmatic targeted one, both frankly not as satisfying as we would all probably like:

#### The General Solution

It is, sadly, very difficult and verbose — but possible — to access the parameter information (or return type information) of function overload types. As described in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function), it's just a limitation of `Parameters` and `ReturnType` that they don't handle overloads the way we might want. Your question is a great example of that. Here's a simpler one ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigG8AoKMqACgGsIQAuKAIhwkYBoowBDAJy4FsAzg0JQAZhh6DgDaTwzIA5lAC+ASgYA3LBgAmAblLlqtBo2AB3LO068BwolEERUOXbODylqjVG17DFUNiUEhYBBR0bGQAaVp8KAAFO34IYAgpAB44JDRMHAA+AG0ABgBdQwB6SvIAPQB+YmqoAAlEAAt6gEJ6qABJKGB2hSoofixpKCwxKERBKCtEABtdKAgAD0h0KAADZmRWKAAfJktrHY4AI0RgJpqhrmAAcnmAKzngKGQsT6HoCy4ICgGE+GEEADpKAAVdoZCAvWaCRBcJZLIFcKCKLBYVY8CBcQQ4O7iLA8Qaw5xQJYYfggx7ReYKcnQRQQA58JZQVAEiBXG7ggVqYhAA)):

```typescript
type MyFunction = {
    (key: "one", params: { first: string }): void;
    (key: "two", params: { second: string }): void;
};

type MyFunctionKey = Parameters<MyFunction>[0];
//   ^? type MyFunctionKey = "two"
// Huh?!? I think most of us would expect `"one" | "two"`, but
// that's just not the way it is. (There's usually a good reason
// for these limitations in the general case, but...)
```

But it **is** possible *within reason*, where "reason" in this case is a sensible maximum number of possible overloads of the function. Let's take six as our maximum overloads limit.

As you can see from [Titian's answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52761156/157247), it's possible to know how many overloads a function has, and to infer their parameter lists. For example:

```typescript
type Whatever<F> =
    F extends {
        (...args: infer Params1): any);
        (...args: infer Params2): any);
    }
        ? // This branch is used if F has **exactly** two overloads
        : // Otherwise this one is
;
```

We can use that mechanism to handle 2, 3, 4, 5...up to whatever reasonable limit you want possible sets of overloads. So here's the first part of our puzzle, the `MyFunctonParams` that dispatches based on how many overloads there are to a parameters helper type:

```typescrpt
type MyFunctionParams<KeyType> =
    MyFunction extends {
        (...args: infer P1): any;
        (...args: infer P2): any;
    }
        ? ParamsHelper<KeyType, P1, P2>
        : MyFunction extends {
              (...args: infer P1): any;
              (...args: infer P2): any;
              (...args: infer P3): any;
          }
        ? ParamsHelper<KeyType, P1, P2, P3>
        : MyFunction extends {
              (...args: infer P1): any;
              (...args: infer P2): any;
              (...args: infer P3): any;
              (...args: infer P4): any;
          }
        ? ParamsHelper<KeyType, P1, P2, P3, P4>
        : MyFunction extends {
              (...args: infer P1): any;
              (...args: infer P2): any;
              (...args: infer P3): any;
              (...args: infer P4): any;
              (...args: infer P5): any;
          }
        ? ParamsHelper<KeyType, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5>
        : MyFunction extends {
              (...args: infer P1): any;
              (...args: infer P2): any;
              (...args: infer P3): any;
              (...args: infer P4): any;
              (...args: infer P5): any;
              (...args: infer P6): any;
          }
        ? ParamsHelper<KeyType, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6>
        : never;
```

`ParamsHelper`'s job is to match the `KeyType` we provide with the first element of each parameter tuples we pass it (your `key`) and provide the type of the second element (your `params`):

```typescript
type ParamsHelper<
    KeyType,
    P1 extends any[],
    P2 extends any[] = [never, never],
    P3 extends any[] = [never, never],
    P4 extends any[] = [never, never],
    P5 extends any[] = [never, never],
    P6 extends any[] = [never, never]
> = KeyType extends P1[0]
    ? P1[1]
    : KeyType extends P2[0]
    ? P2[1]
    : KeyType extends P3[0]
    ? P3[1]
    : KeyType extends P4[0]
    ? P4[1]
    : KeyType extends P5[0]
    ? P5[1]
    : KeyType extends P6[0]
    ? P6[1]
    : never;
```

That's it! Now we get the desired result, provided `MyFunction` doesn't have more than six overloads (or whatever limit you decide to set):

```typescript
type OneParams = MyFunctionParams<"one">;
//   ^? type OneParams = { first: string; }

type TwoParams = MyFunctionParams<"two">;
//   ^? type TwoParams = { second: string; }
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigG8AoKMqACgGsIQAuKAIhwkYBoowBDAJy4FsAzg0JQAZhh6DgDaTwzIA5lAC+ASgYA3LBgAmAblLlqtBo2AB3LO068BwolEERUOXbODylqjVG17DFUNiUEgoAAU7IQAJCAAbSB4AHiMyAGlaABVwCDZUiIBGKAgAD2AIZF1BKC5kEABtAF088giAJmKyiqqauqb8KHrkCE0IHg5h0Z5m-PCAZk7yyurahsaBoZGxia3plvJwgBZF7pW+9YJNqZ2pmdbwgFYT5d61jcntqA+92YA2Z56q36l2+NzGjWIAD4BhkQNkwqUlj1wgV6gAGCGtAD8hXqBUx5AYsPh0ERp3a6IJZBx4TaeKpUCJWRyAOq80p+Rpc3p+SZcJZZJeRw52Iihx5rT5JNZEQeIvINLl+N5UGJAq6Qt+8upES1yslX12wVC0DgSDQmBwkT4QiSasg0Lw+TNKHQ2Fwgp6JFarQoADoA7xFA4FGIxoVfKtDD7jAG-UGQ8gwzx2pG6tHyCp8qLrfZYgkxnbmZAOCjS21IdnCbAEK7LR6NV6qzGyP7AzxgwxQ+GUWmQBmWz62-GO4nk6mGFHmy3hwmu0me3M+wOW1nBzSooJ84ki-yS4Vy6W5pXBwwXRb3TLvYOh3G51Buyne5P09OY7PR-Px7Tl2-b+3OwfBcnyXF9+z-X070-IDv0OX8b1UacNxtLd4h3e1cgPdoj1LQ4TxbM9awvHArwg2MALHHsCnghDyJHQDHwnV4VwQj8GOAiJQOYsjWyg9jYJo2jKD4yinweQTVyQiJN23QsMNLApD043DSwefCY0I803RIz1qmvIS2NEiMwJYm9DK-Hs2gk1iRIskDrLM2yYJ7OCTJ44SKLs2UHMHcznKfX4fMzKTcxiNC5OLTCy2w5SxVU0tfnUn0GG+Y0WQAeWGULqgIc9tOQbKkmYYZGEhQwAHpyvIAA9LFiBCFlMisbKBjy+tCvMKxSoqqqyFq4ggA)

In that example, `MyFunctionParams` is tied to `MyFunction`, but we could make a generic version if we wanted that we passed the function type into. Seemed overkill for your example, but [here that is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigG8AoKMqACgGsIQAuKAIhwkYBoowBDAJy4FsAzg0JQAZhh6DgDaTwzIA5lAC+ASgYA3LBgAmAblLlqtBo2AB3LO068BwolEERUOXbODylqjVG17DFUNiUEgoAAU7IQAJCAAbSB4AHiMyAGlaABVwCDZUiIBGKAgAD2AIZF1BKC5kEABtAF088giAJmKyiqqauqb8KHrkCE0IHg5h0Z5m-PCAZk7yyurahsaBoZGxia3plvJwgBZF7pW+9YJNqZ2pmdbwgFYT5d61jcntqA+92YA2Z56q36l2+NzGjWIAD4BhkQNkwqUlj1wgV6gAGCGtAD8hXqBUx5AYsPh0ERp3a6IJZBx4TaeKpUCJWRyAOq80p+Rpc3p+SZcJZZJeRw52Iihx5rT5JNZEQeIvINLl+N5UGJAq6Qt+8upES1yslX12wVC0FiCTGSSQaEwOBJHDVkGheHyAHoAFRQN0u-JW9DYZDSwU9EitVoUAB0kd4igcCjEY0KvlWhlDxkj4ejseQ8Z47STdRT5BU+VFkT4MXiiSSDtyhQ4tMhJcJUF9NoD6qR1RDqZ7EajPBjDDjCZR+ZAhZ7ob7GYHWZzeYYyabk+nmaH2ZHczHE57xcnNKigjNVZr9YK9ba9bmjcnDFb-sDGuDy976bXUGHudHi4LL9Tq9ndd51pbc-ynN9AI-Dcvy3H9xzAsMIMHKDgMOUDJzIPcewPcsj0rC1Tzrdor3rQ4bx7O8UD9W0O3JbsMLTftkM-RM4J3BiAOY6CF1ediMM4udN3QhjGJnLjUOEkTKCQwSvweSTdxfHD7GPAjmUgM8LxIsV6wecjU0o60H1ol56JEgSgJHAoFI4mTLK-NobP4uyUKEtiENE98WKOJyVxc7z5PcqSyAs1yv1+XyiyUiJD1U5JCJRLSIjmUjdPrX59NDBhvmNFk4HvHAy3sat1IgJ0oDipJ8qott7VKyFcrCAB5YYiqEAZqqMwrDySZhhkYBriBdF1yAAPSxYgQhZTIrDa6oCE66jkDm3rLGsQbhrGiagA).

#### The Pragmatic Targeted Solution

If we **just** want to handle `MyFunction`, we might take a more concise and targeted approach, like this:

```typescript
type MyFunction1 = {
    (key: "one", params: { first: string }): void;
};
type MyFunction2 = {
    (key: "two", params: { second: string }): void;
};
type MyFunction = MyFunction1 & MyFunction2;

type MyFunctionParams<KeyType> =
    KeyType extends Parameters<MyFunction1>[0]
    ? Parameters<MyFunction1>[1]
        : KeyType extends Parameters<MyFunction2>[0]
        ? Parameters<MyFunction2>[1]
            : never;

type OneParams = MyFunctionParams<"one">;
//   ^? type OneParams = { first: string; }

type TwoParams = MyFunctionParams<"two">;
//   ^? type TwoParams = { second: string; }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbIIxQF4oBvAKCgqgAoBrCEALigCIcJmAaKMAQwCceAWwDOTYlABmGPsOBNZfDMgDmUAL4BKJgDcsGACYBuUmuOhIsBCnTZkAJkIlylWvSbNgAdyydu-IaIkUMIQqDj68sCKKupaULoGxqak5tBwSGiYOI7p1ll4UABklhk2OHbGKeBpVpm2AAr+IgA8ANL0ACrVAHyEzhTtIF0WEAAewBDI+sJQjQKCEBMyzbl1OLjdANoADAC6-VAA-LNNixDLq2V4W7j7lPdQTIPD0GMTUzNzQmcXtVd2Wz2B3uxy+CyWwhWf3yAM2t2BDwoTGQEG050qqSgAHkUWCZkRLvk8c1WCjmN1jAB6SmUAB6h1IVQsHW8eJy0IaTUhHm85KpNIo9NIQA)

Not nearly as satisfying, and of course every time you add another overload, you have to edit the `MyFunctionParams` type to handle it, but sometimes something simpler and targeted is better, it depends on your situation.

Comment: Whoa?! Well, that's something! My usecase has ~26 overloads (from the Firebase sdk), so I guess I'll keep my statically typed version. Thank you very much for the quick and detailed answer, learned a bunch!

Comment: @AnatoleLucet - Yeah, it's...something. I didn't know that until I was struck by "Why am I just getting `"two"` for `Parameters<MyFunction>[0]`?" Then I found that other question and ... well, it's "fun." :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Let's do the "opposite" here... Using a generic type, and a map of keys to parameters, we can get the original `MyFunction` type back like this:

```
type PMap = {
    one: { first: string };
    two: { second: string };
};

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type MyF<T extends keyof PMap> = (key: T, params: PMap[T]) => void;

type MyFunction = UnionToIntersection<keyof PMap extends infer U extends keyof PMap ? U extends U ? MyF<U> : never : never>;
```

And this means you'll be able to get what you want like this:

```
type MyFunctionParams<T extends keyof PMap> = Parameters<MyF<T>>[1];
```

Quite long but extensible and does the job.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzPXEN)

Comment: Definitely the way to go if you own the code! Unfortunately for me, the types come from a third party library, so I can't get away from the overloads.

Comment: *"Quite long but extensible and does the job."* No nearly so long as doing it the other way. :-D

Comment: Frankly overloaded functions aren't really something you need to wrangle with, which is why TypeScript doesn't really have this thing down in the dirt quite yet :p