# typescript util type that can change the return type of all function signatures/overloads to a new type

Tags: typescript

I have a type in a library that I want to modify by changing the return type of every function signature in this type.

```js
interface Chainer<Subject> {  
  (chainer: 'be.a', type: string): Cypress.Chainable<Subject>
  (chainer: 'be.above', value: number | Date): Cypress.Chainable<Subject>
  // ... many many more overloads here
}
```

I want to create a util type that can convert all the function signatures to have a different return type.

```js
// This is the util that should change the return type
type RemapFunctionReturnType<T, U> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? (...args: P) => U : never;

type ModifiedChainer = RemapFunctionReturnType<Chainer<any>, number>;

// All return types changed to number
// interface ModifiedChainer<Subject> {  
//   (chainer: 'be.a', type: string): number; 
//   (chainer: 'be.above', value: number | Date): number;
//   // ... many many more overloads here
// }
```

Need help with getting the RemapFunctionReturnType recrusive for all signatures. This is what I have tried so far but it only works for a single signature:

```js
type RemapFunctionReturnType<T, U> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any & infer Next ? (...args: P) => U | RemapFunctionReturnType<Next, U> : never;
```

Comment: This is a design limitation or missing feature of TypeScript, see [ms/TS#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732).  Overloads cannot (easily) be programmatically manipulated in the type system; generally speaking you will only get the last signature.  Any workaround here will necessarily only work for some arbitrarily chosen finite number of overloads, and will involve writing utility types that scale in size with that number.  If you are doing this for a single type,  you should just copy the type definition and do a find-replace on it, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining (assuming I don't find a duplicate). If not, what am I missing? (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me.)

Comment: I see that's rather unfortunate. I have been just copying and modifying these types but was looking for a way to not have to duplicate work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently a limitation of TypeScript that [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) cannot easily be programmatically manipulated in the type system.  When you directly  *call* an overloaded function, the compiler will resolve the call with the appropriate call signature from the list depending on the arguments.

But when you try to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) or [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to probe overloaded functions in the type system, they will invariably appear as if they had just a single call signature (usually the last one on the list).  There's an open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732) for conditional types like your `RemapFunctionReturnType` to return something better, but for now it's not part of the language.

---

The workarounds I know of to tease an overloaded type into an ordered list of its constituent call signatures only support up to some arbitrary fixed number of call signatures.  See [Parameters generic of overloaded function doesn't contain all options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59535995/2887218) and [Typescript: ReturnType of overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52760509/2887218).  The following thing works-ish for up to four overloads:

```
type Overloads<T> =
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3; (...args: infer A4): infer R4
  } ?
  [(...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2, (...args: A3) => R3, (...args: A4) => R4] :
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3
  } ?
  [(...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2, (...args: A3) => R3] :
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2
  } ?
  [(...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2] :
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1
  } ?
  [(...args: A1) => R1] :
  any
```

And you see that this definition scales in size with the *square* of the number of overloads you want to be able to support.  Armed with a "large enough" `Overloads` helper, you could write these:

```
type FromOverloads<T extends readonly any[]> =
    { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void }[number] extends 
    (x: infer U) => void ? U : never;

type ModifyReturn<T extends readonly ((...args: any) => any)[], U> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => void ?   
    (...args: A) => U : never };
```

Which would give you the type you're looking for (an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of functions in TypeScript is equivalent to an overloaded function):

```
type ModifiedChainer = FromOverloads<ModifyReturn<Overloads<Chainer>, number>>
/* type ModifiedChainer = 
     ((chainer: "be.a", type: string) => number) & 
     ((chainer: "be.above", value: number | Date) => number) 
*/
```

---

That's great, but if you're only writing `Overloads<T>` in order to generate `ModifiedChainer`, then you'll necessarily be doing a lot of extra manual work to avoid a medium amount of extra manual work.  So it's almost certainly not worth it.

Until and unless something like microsoft/TypeScript#29732 is implemented, you might as well just find the definition of `Chainer` and do a manual find-and-replace in an IDE, and just remind yourself to check for upstream changes to the original `Chainer` type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMCeyDeAUMicnAFzICMhAvoaJLIigMLpyjQHGkAUCDlyiUA5ACMIAOjiiANMjA4ADhEoBnMFGwBKShmw5eJAUJDQxkmeID2ANwjzkduABsArmuQh3AW0lQyAA+yAAicJB6aJgguMbIAPQJyFKpyL5wIHgZWek2UCj20K42cAAm6sjo0BB0hIRKqsgA8g5QJeXqADyoAHzIALzxqMgQAB6QIBU8pLPIfKkyUFjqlKAw3ACCVFHr3ABKVADc84twy6vIe4GbAEy7IBuB+7dH8bMLqecra49bAMwPJ7Ifb-E6fJY-K5-G4AFiBB1h8VoyAA-PEANoQ76XbY6Qb9Q4KbEXSh3fEDQm3YlnUnITaAgkg-40r50zbwpn7WEAXWQ5GGowmECmlSIc34tKh13pO1+wMO4Kllxl5PlB1e70lbOlMPpgPVz3+yLRmJJULxXKorMhuPuXOppx1uMZlOZfIFsxG40m03FEqdtsNsoRz2OgZxwbV0IVtxN6NmWOVZJ2Vptkfp9rdLw9gp9Ir9WpMyZjWzlpbD8bNJct2aoudmmSMDRUKAAYlAbL5WsVShUekLfZUCuUbCBXHgmxief0hrN8MgMQBpaHIADWEBwNhgaB5lD4Y30y55FP6dhswDKyFoGJ8-mgfPzovmh4ryAAqqfnBer6iP-zvAgNo3hbJoAFkbDKYAYBwfYIDAdwoBAAcn2mEcyjHCd5nNS4my-PDpwUd9Z3iBdl1XDctx3VA9zQY9BwLSocKjL9z0vNEI3ZL93wA8w2mvEDGhQCCoJgYAIDKdhOHMQIBmQDsux7do+26EToNg+DEOQpSOn7KThF6BQ7wCXpekIBIACpFFbZA1LEiT9JkwZkHePhTGkixkAAIisOAvIUISNC0XQmWM6B8QAMhcuY3MEDyRG83zbAcfznDcTxKDCwIQnCSJQr8AJ8UICyEkIIA)