# How to access type override definition?

Tags: typescript

I need to access a type of a function that has override.

[image]

In this example, I want to get the return type of `getToken(code: string)` function.

How do I do it?

```
type GetTokenResponse = (typeof OAuth2Client)['prototype']['getToken'][???];
```

Comment: ① Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) ② I think you want to use the term "overload" and not "override" here, since the latter is different (assuming I'm reading your screenshot correctly, kind of hard for me to see it, refer to prev point) ③ There is no scalable/programmatic way to manipulate overloads like this that works in general.  See [ms/TS#32164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164) and linked issues for discussion.

Comment: This answer might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60822641/1147772