# Problem with extending an overloaded method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

In a parent class, I define a method with different parameters: an index in a store or an element, and depending on the parameter, I get the element from the store by its index or just use the given element.
Thus, I use overloading to define these methods:

```
class Parent<T> {
  items: T[] = [];
  item: T = {} as T;

  applyMethod(index: number): void;
  applyMethod(item: T): void;
  applyMethod(param: number | T): void {
    if (typeof param === 'number') {
      param = this.items[param];
    }
    this.item = param;
  }
}

class Child1<T> extends Parent<T> {
  // In my application, I actually add an id: string overload.
  override applyMethod(param: number | T): void {
    // Do something more before calling:
    super.applyMethod(param);
  }
}

class Child2<T> extends Parent<T> {
  override applyMethod(param: number | T): void {
    if (typeof param === 'number') {
      super.applyMethod(param);
    } else {
      super.applyMethod(param);
    }
  }
}
```

See it in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALgHgCoD5oG8AoaaASzSQFsIAuaLAbQF1oBeaZgbmLIsrqxsCAX2iR63HmAAO0kAE8AskjQALAPYATABTkqdFAFdKAIyQIAlHQBu60pu4kZcpSo069-elei37jsVkFZTUtXT4DYzMEaAAfbxs7TQIeElIAM2htNHlpJHVMzzZWdgByI1NzUosUkjreKiE1UggAOk8IBk8mAJJhVOhmtqL2TwD%20-sJQSBgAYVVSEE0ARmw8JAAPChRNGHhkdDXa6HVrcwR7JECXEPdw-WgK6LiE3yTjkghDPIRW52C3GFPBZxoRJtMoNB5otNAAmI6bba7OCIVCYXDHU7nS7XAGhDwRR5RcwvLA%20PzJIj1DJZHJ5AoNSjFMpPKo1Kn1aBfH5-IKufH3SgggaiJAgCBXDn1bnmXk3QEEqjC%20r9PpgwhAA) too.

In Child1, I have an error:

```
No overload matches this call.\
  Overload 1 of 2, '(index: number): void', gave the following error.\
    Argument of type 'number | T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.\
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(item: T): void', gave the following error.\
    Argument of type 'number | T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.\
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number | T'.(2769
```

I can workaround it as shown in Child2, but it is quite strange / stupid.

Another workaround would be to define `applyMethod(param: any): void {}` instead of `number | T`. It is classical and that's what I did initially, but I found out that TS only sees the `param: any` parameter definition, thus I lose typing.

I chose another way, calling `super.applyMethod(param as any);`. At least, the inputs keep their typings.

Is there another way, more elegant? Did I miss something?

Comment: Why is `Parent`'s method overloaded as opposed to accepting `number | T` to start with? The "elegant" approach is to avoid overloads where possible, as overloads have issues (such as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107 which is the one most relevant here)  In the example here it is quite possible to avoid them. If that doesn't work for your actual use case, please [edit] to show a [mre].  Otherwise I could post an answer with more details.  Let me know.

Comment: I simplified the case to show only the problem. As indicated in the comments, I actually add an overload (string parameter) to the child class.
Indeed, I can remove the overloads (it solves the problem), although a use case I saw is to personalize the JSDoc comments for each overload. Probably not compelling, I agree.
The issue doesn't stop me, but I find strange that I need useless tests, or a cast, to avoid this problem. That's the main point of my post.
In short: is this a bug (or limitation) of TS?

Comment: I will just remove the overloads, I am not fond of them anyway. They come from some legacy code, I can simplify the code.

Comment: It's https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107, so technically it's a "missing feature" of TS (they don't call it a "limitation" or "bug", and maybe someday it will be implemented). I can write up an answer, if you agree it fully addresses the question

Comment: Looks like it is happenind due to TypeScript's inability to narrow the type of the generic parameter T in runtime. 

As an workaround with overloads, you can define guard type `type TypeOrNumber<T> = T extends number ? T : T;`

and then cast `item as TypeOrNumber<T>`

Comment: That is probably better than `any`, but doesn't make big difference from `Child2` workaround

Comment: Note that you can always add a third overload to the parent method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLARkW), which is one of the recommended workarounds to ms/TS#14107.  Shall I write up an answer here, PhiLho?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, you can write an answer with the reference to the issue. As you suggested initially, I am just removing the overloads, it works better! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in TypeScript have various limitations that make them hard to work with.  The limitation you're running into is that currently the type checker only resolves calls to exactly *one* call signature. It will not attempt to *combine* call signatures.

If you have two call signature like `(x: string) => string` and `(y: number) => number`, then you can call `f("")` or `f(0)`, but not `f(Math.random()<0.5?"":0)`, because the latter would require the compiler to combine both call signatures into something like `(xOrY: string | number) => string | number`.  That is, it would need to synthesize call signatures corresponding to [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the parameters of each call signature.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) asking for such support, but for now it's not part of the language.

---

Until and unless that is implemented, you'll need to work around it.  If you can avoid overloads entirely that is often the best approach, since there are multiple ways in which overloads are not well-supported by the type system ([Typescript: ReturnType of overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52760509/2887218) and many other examples can be found).

If you do want to keep the overloads, then one of the workarounds (as mentioned in the GitHub issue) is to manually add an overload (at the bottom) that includes the relevant union:

```
class Parent<T> {
  items: T[] = [];
  item: T = {} as T;

  applyMethod(index: number): void;
  applyMethod(item: T): void;
  applyMethod(param: number | T): void; // <-- add catch-all overload
  applyMethod(param: number | T): void {
    if (typeof param === 'number') {
      param = this.items[param];
    }
    this.item = param;
  }
}
```

Now the call inside the child class works as written, because it can be resolved to the third call signature from the parent:

```
class Child1<T> extends Parent<T> {
  override applyMethod(param: number | T): void {
    super.applyMethod(param); // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALgHgCoD5oG8AoaaASzSQFsIAuaLAbQF1oBeaZgbmLIsrqxsCAX2iR63HmAAO0kAE8AskjQALAPYATABSkUmpAA86KAK6UARkgQBKOgDd1pTdxIy5SlRp3kqAu9COzq5isgrKalra0ohg-NBmltbQAD70AUEu0AD02dAYALQFYpqa0MBgaMCqBWAgINDq9tYg6mCaUmGekToxCHEm5lYIqekOTmVEJCSkAGbQ2mjy0kjq831xbKzsAOSJwzs2BDzT0BuUQmqkEAB0vtQM50whJMIn0Fe390LnIW9vhFAkBgAGFVKQQJoAIzYPBGCj6GDwZDoWHHEhNawIZxIUIeCLeaKxeL7ZJpLAZCbo6YQUwrBA3dzhLxRc42Tg5PLqADWYHkPH+hEIQA)

Answer (score 0):

As jcalz suggested, using overloads can be problematic.
One advantage they have is to allow to personalize the JSDoc comments depending on the overload:

```
/**
 * Set the active item to the item at the specified index .
 *
 * @param index - The index of the item to be set as active.
 */
setActiveItem(index: number): void;
/**
 * Set the active item to the specified item.
 *
 * @param item - The item to be set as active.
 */
setActiveItem(item: I): void;
setActiveItem(param: number | I): void {
}
```

Another advantage is that they can allow different return types depending on input, but unless you have legacy code, I feel it is better to have distinct method names in this case.

Once I remove the overloads, I must make more generic doc:

```
/**
 * Set the active item to the given item or the one at the specified index.
 *
 * @param param - The item itself or the index of the item to be set as active.
 */
setActiveItem(param: number | I): void {
}
```

It simplifies the code, at least, and the code is a bit more readable in the end, at the price of a slightly more convoluted JSDoc. I feel it is OK, then.