# Is it possible to create "promisified" type from function type, stripping anything in arguments that looks like callback and leaving the rest?

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

I'm thinking about writing some "promisified" equivalents of functions and having trouble understanding how can I get all parameters except those that does look like callback (they usually have 2 arguments and look like that: `(error, result) => void`.

Those functions are in different module and they are defined in .d.ts files. Meaning it would be very useful to get those arguments because some of them are inside module as private types.

Examples of such functions types (you can notice callback can be anywhere, as well as there can be multiple callbacks):

```
type FuncLoad1 = (arg1: string, arg2: string, callback: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void) => void;

type FuncLoad2 = (arg1: string, callback: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void, arg2: string) => void;

type FuncLoad3 = (arg1: string, callbackInProgress: (progress: number) => void, arg2: string, callbackOnCompleted: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void) => void;
```

Is it possible to obtain automatically this type from one above?

```
(arg1: string, arg2: string) => Promise<string | null>
```

As you can notice, there can be any number of callbacks and they can be anywhere. Arguments that are not function is all that is left in the processed type.

Comment: ① Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can work from as a starting point. Right now this is a bit too theoretical to be a good fit for SO. ② Do you just care about types or do you need to worry about implementation? ③ You can't easily manipulate overloaded functions. I suggest you remove that part of the question to keep it focused and if you care about workarounds or ways of trying to extract types from overloads there are existing SO questions more appropriate to that, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/52760509/2887218

Comment: @jcalz done. Tried to add example

Comment: You don't "*strip away anything in arguments that looks like callback*". You specifically strip the *last* argument that must be that particular callback.

Comment: Have you looked at the type declarations of the many existing `promisify` functions found in libraries (or elsewhere on the web)?

Comment: @Bergi I did not. I will check them, thanks!

Comment: Right, what if there are multiple callbacks? Is it the first one? The last one? Some combination of both?  What if there are parameters after the callback? Or do we assume that it's the last parameter? I'm hoping for a bit more test cases in your [mre].

Comment: Also note that Node [comes with promisify built in](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: @jcalz tried to add more test cases.

Comment: Could you explain how `FuncLoad3` is supposed to turn into `(arg1: string, arg2: string) => Promise<string | null>`? How do we know that `(progress: number) => void` should be silently dropped while `(error: string | null, result: string | null) => void` should be used for the return type?  I don't know if it's just "the last callback is probably the one we want" or if it's something else.  Note that you can't just say "the one that takes two parameters" because of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).

Comment: @jcalz yes this is interesting issue. I don't know if it's possible in typescript type system to check parameter name and check if one of the parameters called "error" or "err" for example - and then this is the function for the result.

Comment: No, parameter names are unobservable to the type system, that's impossible to do. Even if it were possible in the type system, though, how would that work at runtime? Do you have some implementation of a `promisify`-like function that you want to give a type to? Would it try to... read the code of the callback it was handed in order to see the *names* of the parameter?  I'm just wondering what we're tying to do here.

Comment: @jcalz well... In general I am looking at multiple functions of cocos creator game engine (typescript). It has lots of functions/methods with callbacks. I wondered if it's possible to create general "promisify" function by myself and this is the reason why I asked. You lead me to the modifications of the question with your comments and now I can see that it would be just better to write by hand those promisified functions instead of creating "magic" promisify that accepts everything and returns callback result.

Comment: So what should we do here to close out this question? Should I write "there's no reasonable way to accomplish this" as an answer? Or should we remove the question? Or do you want to come up with some more tractable version of the question which could be answered?

Comment: I think it would be nice for you to answer this question with "there is no reasonable way to accomplish this". Question remains as it is now. I will accept the answer.

Comment: Okay I’ll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no reasonable way to accomplish this as stated.

---

It's easy enough to write a type function which removes all the callback-like parameters from a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

```
type TupleExclude<T extends any[], U, A extends any[] = []> =
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? TupleExclude<R, U, F extends U ? A : [...A, F]> : A;
```

And then you can have a utility type that returns a `Promise` of the second parameter of any callback in that parameter list:

```
type Promisify<T extends (...args: any) => void> =
  (...args: TupleExclude<Parameters<T>, (e: any, r: any) => void>) =>
    Promise<Parameters<Extract<Parameters<T>[number], (e: any, r: any) => void>>[1]>;

type PFL1 = Promisify<FuncLoad1>;
// type PFL1 = (args_0: string, args_1: string) => Promise<string | null>

type PFL2 = Promisify<FuncLoad2>;
// type PFL2 = (args_0: string, args_1: string) => Promise<string | null>

type PFL3 = Promisify<FuncLoad3>;
// type PFL3 = (args_0: string, args_1: string) => Promise<string | null | undefined>
```

This is fairly close to what you're asking for, except for the return type of `PFL3`. The main issue here is that there's no simple way to distinguish between the `(progress: number) => void` and `(error: string | null, result: string | null) => void` types to say that the second one is "the" callback you care about.  The former only declares a single parameter, but [functions of fewer parameters are assignable to functions of more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters), this making them [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).

It's potentially possible to imagine really digging through the type system to try to find "the" callback for that example, but then what happens if you have multiple two-arg callbacks? You can't use the *names* of the parameters like `error` and `result`. Parameter names are intentionally unobservable in the type system (see [microsoft/TypeScript#55736](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55736)). But even if you *could* do this, you should back up and try to imagine *implementing* a `promisify` function that works this way.

---

Presumably you want to write a function of the form

```
declare function promisify<T extends (...args: any)=>void>(f: T): Promisify<T>;
```

which lets you call

```
declare const: fl3: FuncLoad3;
const pfl3 = promisify(fl3);
pfl3("abc", "def");
```

Well, it's going to need a runtime implementation. That implementation has no access to TypeScript's type system, which is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types) by the time JavaScript code runs. So it has to somehow call `fl3` using the arguments `"abc"` and `"def"`. How would it know how many callbacks `fl3` expects and where to put them?  The type `(arg1: string, callbackInProgress: (progress: number) => void, arg2: string, callbackOnCompleted: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void) => void;` does not exist at runtime, and a function object at runtime doesn't expose much information about what parameters it takes (there's [the `length` property of functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), but all that tells you is the number of required parameters). There just isn't enough information at runtime for you to do anything.

So that's the answer to the question as asked; this is not really possible in the type system and it's completely impossible at runtime.

---

If you wanted to convert this into something possible, you'd have to come up with some way of telling your function where the callbacks are expected to go.  The easiest thing to do is to just declare: there's going to be a single callback and it's going to be at the end, and it's going to expect the result as the second argument.  If you did that, things proceed quite directly:

```
function promisify<A extends any[], R>(f:
  (...args: [...A, (error: any, result: R) => void]) => void
): (...args: A) => Promise<R>;
function promisify(f: Function) {
  return (...args: any) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    f(...args, (err: any, result: any) => {
      if (err == null)
        resolve(result);
      else
        reject(err);
    })
  })
}

function funcLoad(arg1: string, arg2: string,
  cb: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(null, arg1 + " " + arg2), 1000);
}
const p = promisify(funcLoad);
// const p: (arg1: string, arg2: string) => Promise<string | null>
async function foo() {
  const val = await p("abc", "def");
  console.log(val?.toUpperCase());
}
foo(); // "ABC DEF"
```

You could even write something where `promisify` takes some sort of options object that alters the quantity and/or locations of the callbacks and consults it.  But then you might as well just wrap your function to conform to the "single-callback-at-end" form:

```
// FuncLoad3, not the expected form
function funcLoad3(arg1: string,
  callbackInProgress: (progress: number) => void, arg2: string,
  callbackOnCompleted: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callbackInProgress(123);
    setTimeout(() => callbackOnCompleted(null, arg1 + " " + arg2), 1000);
  }, 1000);
}

// just wrap it
const wrapFunc3 = (arg1: string, arg2: string,
  cb: (error: string | null, result: string | null) => void) =>
  funcLoad3(arg1, (n) => console.log(n), arg2, cb);

// now it works
const p3 = promisify(wrapFunc3);
async function bar() {
  const val = await p3("ghi", "jkl");
  console.log(val?.toUpperCase());
}
bar(); // 123, then "GHI JKL"
```

But all of this is a digression from the question as asked, so I won't go into any detail about how that works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAngBQE4HswEsp8AzNJAbwChqkkAXNGZAMQFdh4AZHEAEwEYkAXiQAKEFgDm-AFxIodLPmCSANEgmSATHIVKV6+CAA2xgEYIA1nNEQsuLLsXLJSAD5JgrU+qzRvdE76rh5epgCUwgB8SABuOPi8kUIx8YkA3JS0DExIbBzcfFrCYpqy8s4GSEamFvDWYnYOQS7unt7Gvv7GgRXBbWHGyakJvOqaOn0uw3GjmdmMLOxcPLwAzCXiUuV6LoYm5lYAksDYOJJ+UFA2MLgX0NftYGZ2M2ljGlKTu1U1h-UAeWAAGE8DBjBA6BBeDYmjhHFMVAMOl0oAEWkjQh03qMcRkaPRFkgACqscEQACiAA94MZWLwIAAeYlICBUqHAXhQDTANAAbQAuuoAKrqACCrPZEE53JAvMFJUFMSEWVoJMlHK5SD5ymIdjy6gAdMbdfqAEoCpAAfhJZIh1Np9KZZpF6mYGulWuF1qQErkfONhrFboFMTkYsyqpyyDOBCIpGZHplYkDmkecrQeN4ytVtFEqakj1J5IddIZjIwEnAkLsUGZUXUtjkGd8zd5Waiw1zatjhCZlaw1ahWDr1MUCDoFarkGHdeJUT5XmediFjTbaFbPMz0VmiSiC-4ocjC1yGGYnEEIl78bQjPyKz4-Ci8yQAHpX4TT+fL6VCwB9AAGDE1E+SQoD-HZKkkGZryZH4QnaUwogJaMkDPThiivXA4xIW970KXgtGfVV30-GNz0w38wMA4Dxn-SDghg7C+0ZeDkSQlCiXQjYsLwQhcLvZYCLWYjaFI1DuM2NMaMREDpIY6Yd1g1ioPY4w2nYBliGUaFkOoABfahiGWOh8BwYAkFuPib0ZCU2U1WV5VXM0olEYgZFVfNjTTf1A2DRp7HhddUXRJAzSzAUs0ocIbALMDwyY6znWI4yOFM8zLOYm83Lke90uASIqFoPw6FYLALK8w0fK3GZgAgAB3NCsogURREuHBjFiCAugAKwgeA6BmIq1WISq00bJpgqQS5QozIbu1oEgAqwYQREGcIFrVdrOpamaenCF81VZYwoAgTbiogPqBtsewDu7fSNtoB7KEMyhUoGsyLPegitmkWjQO+KDVFVeAzFhQKETYrEfGm7peihxChh3d5CtVU66GJfBIBwVg6FamZQdEQY6OkJAAGokAAIip8mAfCdR+AApm7sM+BzIUSySisnDSDcoTVju0i2eADmYBsMp-omYDErjODVOh4xkJAKA0A4JB3vy9WcBwURUdoYWOdiEwShAeqQHwOhLNESmQDMeBKfUSmtMpu79fZjqIENYxzlEI3jCtQ06BwYUYCYLBgWVlrwhZt7td19I3w-SmxQAIWBJAABEKWYSmjJMz71f5vg1l+hSDBBg46ksE4znuK4bjuS5HiXF4sCzEnAeCYH9crqwgVBMByShGFlqC2S1JCnpgLUrM9fkSFMex3H8Z3Yae9qY5Tkbh5RH4LQ1ldtV0cXiAcbx3Wdz+Kv+7BCFh6JlFQMECnqepimJnppBGeZl99IZpmAIxwNpbeqg4YD3h4lRMuckvi0RBmDUekN5aI0nvDZB61ka4miKqb6qwS5lEbAVS+7sIRex9gVDuhgzB3WAZZSB3N+K81ASAcBywD6ZGVqreAhc0oFwsFgC+w1aF+xNmbC2dDraSAABb4AdlTHqlhjAuxfAbD2ZDJC+xMAHIOIcw4R1OrrGO-D46Jy-vvdQdApHSipgAcQABJHCQAAKQANKcFzkAA)